# Handling questions from non native English speakers

Tags: discussion, english

I often see posts which have improper English which is difficult to understand. It is understandable that the OP in such a case is not a native English speaker and asking them to rephrase will probably not help.

How do we handle such questions?

Comment: If the language is so poor that you can't understand what's being asked, flag/vote to close as **unclear what you're asking**.

Comment: If you can understand what they want to say then edit to improve. If you're not sure then ask / confirm in a comment. I see many times where questions get down voted by other non-native English speakers because they can't understand the English in the question, but I, as a native speaker, can understand what they are trying to say. Help them out if you can. Especially for new users as a whole heap of down votes really is not a nice welcome to the site.

Comment: @kjbartel note that, per [the guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *"**Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!** Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you."* I don't think downvoting should be the first response, though; putting it on hold as unclear, as I comment, sends the appropriate message.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it is important but what may be unclear to one person may not be unclear to someone else, particularly when we are speaking cross cultures. Even within English there are multiple dialects or regional flavours which can confuse native speakers.

Comment: @kjbartel That's why it takes 5 votes to close.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To me, closing the question seems worse than a few down votes, which seems worse than a few close votes.  But if you're new to the site, you don't have the privilege to see that the last option has happened until your question has closed.

Comment: @Teepeemm I disagree: downvotes give you a big red -rep (if you have any), whereas putting the question on hold doesn't "cost" you anything and you get a nice banner explaining what you can do to get it reopened.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you down vote a question there is no rep consequence to that.  The only lose re if you down vote an answer

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, I meant that **the OP** loses rep if you downvote their question - I know the downvoter doesn't lose any in either case.

Comment: What makes you think that murdering the English language is reserved exclusively for non-native speakers? ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edit them until they read better, including

- proper spelling,
- proper phrasing,
- proper formatting
- capitalization of the letter "i",
- and so forth.

Asking them to improve the grammar may not be the best use of time or resources, as the language barrier may prove to be too great to take a lot of phrasing and sentence structure into account.

Through this process, don't change the meaning of the question.

Comment: Thank you but as @jonrsharpe mentioned, it's alright to flag them?

Comment: If it's *really* bad, then yes, that would make sense.

Comment: ref:Capitalizing I, proper spelling. It's not easy to tell, but there are people who do not know the language well enough, and then there are lazy people who do not care enough.

Comment: Unclear is unclear. But being nice about it, fixing 'unclear' if you can is a good first step.

Comment: I think it would be valuable if there was an easy way to know their native language. In some cases it would be possible for another non-native speaker to help the OP correct the question to a better English, using the chat.

Comment: +1 for the *capitalization of the letter "i"*. Greatest. Pet peeve. Ever.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to get them to explain the gist of the idea in their native language (in the comments) and get a speaker of that language to edit the question. I dunno how that'd work, but it seems better than hoping you're right or giving up.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a very good idea.  First, Stack Overflow is an English only site, and there aren't any guarantees that there's a native speaker online to translate the text before it gets closed for being "unclear".

Comment: I agree with QPaysTaxes, it could be a start. Every person trying to do a question in another language MUST (almost) try to understand how the language is in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes the grammar is so bad you can't tell the intent. Instead of trying to interpret it, _leave that specific part alone_. Edit around it, and ask the author to clarify.

Comment: What do you do when you don't understand what they are trying to communicate? In that case, your answer of editing the question does not apply.

Comment: @Goose:  In those scenarios, you would vote to close as "unclear".  My answer more referred to broken or incomplete English which is understandable, but not *clear*.

Comment: In my experience, the majority of questions from non-native English speakers are typically incomprehensible, and fixing the grammar, phrasing, etc. still leaves the question a mystery. Though it does seem a little mean, I like what @Makoto said. In end, unclear is unclear - no exception.