# How do I deal with non-English content?

Tags: support, faq, english

What action should I take if I come across non-English content?
Does the amount of non-English content make any difference?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 395, accepted):

### [We require English on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684).

- **Questions** not written in English [should be closed as **"*Not written in English*"**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422751/introducing-a-new-close-reason-specifically-for-non-english-questions) (found under the category, "A community-specific reason").

  This close reason links to [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions), which contains more details about why Stack Overflow requires all content to be in English, advice for non-native speakers, and suggestions of where else someone can go to ask a question in a language other than English.

  (Prior to [this explicit close reason being introduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422034/proposing-a-community-specific-closure-reason-for-non-english-content), questions not written in English were either closed as "needs more details or clarity" or a custom close reason such as "I'm voting to close this question because it is not written in English." Therefore, you may see older non-English questions closed for these reasons. It is technically permissible to continue to use these reasons to close non-English questions, but it is *strongly preferred* that you use the new reason created specifically for non-English questions. There is no reason not to use it, and it provides clearer/better guidance for all parties.)

  **Non-English questions should not be translated into English** by anyone other than the original poster (OP). Translating a question for a non-English speaker sets them and all participants up for a poor experience, due to the OP not being able to follow and respond to feedback from comments, understand answers, or get assistance from the Help Center.

  Relatedly, it is [*not recommended* to raise a custom flag to ask a ♦ moderator to migrate non-English questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392318) to other sites. The odds that migration will happen are extremely low and such flags are usually declined, since English-speaking Stack Overflow moderators will not be able to read and evaluate the quality of the question to determine whether it is suitable for migration. Simply close the question as "*Not written in English*" and let [the guidance in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) do its job. There is no need to leave any comments.
- **Answers** not written in English should be flagged as ***"very low quality"***, although *"not an answer"* will also work.
- In **code blocks**, it is acceptable to name variables in any language. A code snippet containing non-English variables that can easily be followed does *not* require flagging or editing. Of course, we strongly *prefer* English, even for variable names, to increase accessibility and readability for our target audience. Comments in code blocks must be written in English, otherwise they're just noise; see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- **Comments** not written in English should be flagged as ***"no longer needed"***, unless they actually meet the requirements of the other flag reasons in translation. If machine translation would not reveal the comment as being rude/abusive, and being a native speaker is required, then it may be appropriate to raise a custom flag on the comment in order to explain your concerns and the actual meaning. In most cases, though, simply deleting the comment is sufficient, which can be accomplished most efficiently with a "no longer needed" flag.

See also:

- [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)
- [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)
- [Can I ask a question in a language other than English?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)
- [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers)