# What can I do with questions with titles not in English?

Tags: discussion, support

If the title of a question is in some language other than English, what should be done? Is there a flag defined for this purpose?

In a recent case, I flagged it for moderator attention. But it was declined, saying:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

What is the course of action to be taken in such a scenario?

Comment: [FAQ article](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/109702)

Comment: Translate it into english?

Comment: In case of a title, if the rest of the question is in English you can suggest a translation (using Google Translate perhaps) or comment that they perhaps forgot to translate something.