# "Requires editing" wrong for a foreign language?

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, triage, english

I reviewed this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11491582
with verdict "Requires editing", since it looked like a real question which could be ok if someone (EDIT: perhaps the OP himself) edited and translated it.

I do not think it is "Unsalvagable" (what I should have voted for according to the audit), since a translation can fix it.

One objection that I had is if the OP would understand english answers at all, but I thought, that on one hand the google translator could help him and on the other hand, the answer is not only for him but for the whole community.

Am I completely lost here? Are questions in foreign languages automatically "Unsalvagable" under any circumstances?

Edit: The main question is: Was it really wrong to give the OP a chance to translate his question or is a foreign language *always* unsalvagable? Or was this just an unfortunate question for an audit? I do not consider this the same question as the proposed duplicate.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2499035) does a good job of explaining the correct approach to non-English questions.

Comment: The system thinks it is "unsalvageable" because it was deleted. You were perhaps not wrong in thinking it can be edited, but the expectation is that the person will ask a question in the right language to start out with.

Comment: @resueman Well, the OP could have translated it himself, non?

Comment: This question can't be salvaged by editing, unless the OP himself edits the question. If someone else edits it, chances are the OP won't understand any of the answers he might get.

Comment: Or [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

Answer (score 2):

This question can't be salvaged by editing, unless the OP himself edits the question.

If someone else edits it, chances are the OP won't understand any of the answers he might get, since there's no telling if the OP even understands English.

Comment: But "can't be salvaged, unless .. " means "Can be salvaged", doesn't it?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. But I've never seen a question being translated by the OP.

Comment: @Ctx SO is not a translation service, really.

Comment: @Deduplicator Noone claimed that at all!

Comment: @Ctx You are arguing that the community should salvage non-english posts by translating though...

Comment: @Deduplicator I have edited the question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @Ctx The OP can always add an intelligible question, yes. Doesn't mean the post is salvagable before he does so.

Comment: @Deduplicator In this case, the question was (probably) ok, just the form wasn't. Please do not compare that with asking a completely different question, which indeed isn't "salvaging".

Comment: @Ctx Read the triage guide. Yes, if the OP had used english, he might have had an acceptable post. Maybe, I didn't try translating. That's irrelevant though.

Comment: @Deduplicator The triage guide does not suggest that this case is unsalvagable.

Comment: Questions in a foreign language are essentially gibberish to those who do not speak that language. That's why SO created the Portuguese, Spanish, Russian, and Japanese flavors. Thus, those questions should be closed or, if in one of those four languages, and of high quality, migrated.

Comment: The problem is determining whether a post in a language you cannot read is of sufficient high quality to be migrated to a localized site. Better to just err on the side of *not* migrating. A user that couldn't find the right site to ask their question is, on balance, unlikely to have asked a high quality question.