# Language used for while asking question

Tags: discussion, languages

While recently looking for new questions, I found a question regarding some error in the button. But that was only the title and the body of question is in some language that I fail to recognize. Why do we not have a logic on this site that will traverse the first line of the body and post the answer on the respective site depending on the language. I so because the questions asked might be relevant and important but unless a majority of people understand it, it will be counted as useless thereby pushing the other questions down.

Comment: Can you write some code that can detect this 100% reliably with no false positives? If so, then please do! That being said, a *[suggestion](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/joke-battles/images/c/cb/Clippy.png/revision/latest?cb=20151209031540)* in the form of "This question looks like it's in Spanish, do you want to go to es.SO?" might be useful, if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you see them, please **flag** questions written in language other than English. Either use "very low quality" or a custom flag ("not written in English").

As for your question, language detection is not an automatic science, and even if it were, we do not have language-specific sites for all possible languages. If someone wants to ask their question on a localized site, we welcome them to do so. But there is no reason to accommodate people who can't be bothered to [follow the rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content).

These questions are indeed useless and unintelligible to the majority of our users, which is why we do not allow them and why you need to flag them as soon as you see them so that they can be removed.