# Flagging non-English post disputed after the post is translated

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer, disputed-flags, english

I was doing a review on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36990359/1). The answer was in an non-English language (with only English code snippets). I marked this as "Not an answer" following Meta guidelines [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/683218):

> We require English on Stack Overflow.
>
> - Questions written in non-English should be closed as *unclear what you're asking.*
> - Answers written in non-English should be flagged as *not an answer.*
>
> ...

But my flag was disputed, and when I looked at it again, [the answer has been translated into English](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36990359/2).

Was my flagging incorrect?

Also, is the flag evaluation based on the flagged version or the current version?

Comment: "disputed" does not mean "incorrect" in English.

Comment: "disputed" doesn't mean you shouldn't have done the flagging. That'd be "declined".

Comment: "disputed" mostly means that you were right, but then the post was fixed before your flag had been reviewed.

Comment: Something similar happened to me. I saw a question that was just "lorem ipsum" the whole way down. I flagged it as abusive. Later, after my flag was declined, I see that they removed it all and added in a question.

Comment: I _really_ wish the term "disputed" were something more descriptive, like  "inconclusive", which seems to be the usual result.  (I would also love the ability to annotate flags other than "moderator attention".)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your flag was disputed [in review.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12220902)

The most current revision is shown in review. As far as I'm aware, moderators also see the most current revision when evaluating a flag.

As you can see, by the time the first person in LQQ review had reviewed the post, it had already been edited. (The post was edited 20 hours ago, and the first review was 13 hours ago.) So by the time anyone reviewed it, the post was already fixed.

In general, the current consensus *is* to flag non-English posts, as you have done, so your flagging was correct. In this case, another user got the same post in a late answer review, and opted to leave a comment to the answerer that English is the required language here. This seems to be what prompted the translation by the answerer.

You can see or access all of this information in [the post's timeline.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36990359/timeline)