# Why is this NAA flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, languages

I reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566992/), which was written in Non-English language [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49566992/1), but translated into English by a different user. I flagged it as "Not an Answer" per meta guidelines.

Last time I encountered this issue ([Flagging non-English post disputed after the post is translated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322337)), the same type of flag was only [disputed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322337). From the answers there, I get the impression that my flag was correct. The flag is disputed because the content changed in the review queue.

However, this time, the flag is declined by a moderator.

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

I would certainly be more cautious on flagging Non-English posts.

Is the policy changing on this?

Comment: The flag as cast was correct IMO, then the post edited, then a mod finally saw it and declined it. The only possible compounding factor was that there *was* useful content in the answer if you strip out the foreign language text, but... that's a hard argument to make. I'll take the opportunity to plug [my edit-after-flag warning script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365091/1849664) for moderators.

Comment: Not sure about policy, but moderators cannot dispute NAA flags. A NAA flag can only be disputed by the review process.

Comment: Yet another time I'm reminded how similar "declined" and "disputed" are when you read past them.

Comment: Same thing happened to me yesterday with this answer which was translated after flagging https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49576475/revisions

Comment: @StephenKennedy how did you know that it's not an answer when you don't know the language it is written in? :) I for one use VLQ flags in cases like that, as in "regular English-speaking SO visitor won't be able to make sense of this text". This has an advantage that my flag resolves as helpful in (rare) cases [when someone translates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365004/839601)

Comment: @gnat To be quite honest I wasn't... mindful of that particular nuance. It seems you're right, VLQ would have been better - thanks for pointing it out to me :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sorry, that was my mistake, I missed that the post had been edited and declined the flag.  (Yes, Undo, I normally do run your script, but I was handling flags on my mobile at the time).

So no, there has been no policy change, you flagged the post correctly at the time.

Note the moderators can only mark NAA flags as either helpful or declined; such flags only end up disputed when a majority of reviewers in the review queue disagree with the flag.

Comment: I need voting advice here. Does an upvote mean: *Thanks for confessing that mistake* and downvote mean: *bad, bad mod*?

Comment: @rene: dunno, what do *you* think will help keep the error rate low? Tough love or nurture? And consider this: I know where you keep your pending flags, it'd be a *shame* if something happened to them...

Comment: The joke's on you, @rene doesn't have any pending flags. :-P

Comment: vote up for mod admitting that he was _wrong_. If you want mods that are always right, hire robots.

Comment: Then lets do that

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not even robots are always right. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdisputed-review-audits%5D+is%3Aq+score%3A1+closed%3Ano) is the proof.

Comment: @DonaldDuck ah yes, but robots pick answers by score. Who downvoted/upvoted them in the first place?