# Why is the Epiphany hat description not written in English?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I see the hat description is given in English. But I just received the Epiphany hat, which has the following Description, which does not look like English to me:

> La Befana vien di notte con le scarpe tutte rotte

Screenshot:

[image]

Is this a bug or something that I don't know? Or what does it mean?

Comment: This question has already been answered on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288705/340816). See also [Befana on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana).

Comment: Quidquid latine dictum, altum videtur.

Comment: The description refers to the [first poem in the wikipedia page about Befana.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana#Poems_and_songs.5B11.5D)

Answer (score 50):

No, it's not a bug. It's an [Italian children's song](http://www.mamalisa.com/?t=es&p=3102) which is connected to Epiphany. A [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to change it back to English has been [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288705/can-we-translate-the-description-of-epiphany-back-to-english). I guess the Stack Overflow developers are exempt from the [English-only policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) :D.

Comment: "The Befana comes at night
In worn out shoes
Dressed like a Roman
Long live the Befana!" in English