# Is it acceptable to write a comment in another language on a non-English post?

Tags: discussion, english

I come across some non-English posts, and for a few of the languages in which the questions are asked I speak the language.

I have seen that it is the rules of Stack Overflow to not allow questions not in English. If I speak the language, Stack Overflow exists in the language, and it is not a VLQ, I tend to leave a comment in the language of the poster redirecting them to the appropriate Stack Exchange site, but I feel like this might violate Stack Overflow's English-only policy. Is it acceptable to do such?

Comment: I would write the comment in both the OP's language *and* in English so that it's clear to other English-speakers that you're just trying to direct them to the correct site.

Comment: @BSMP That's quite fair. I shall being doing that.

Comment: Don't forget to ask them to delete the post ... see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: El sitio Stack Overflow Meta solo se permite hablar en inglés. (The Stack Overflow Meta site only allows speaking in English.)

Comment: @RobertColumbia ¿Veramente? Estoy cansado.

Comment: @EliSadoff Es la verdad. ¿Está Ud. cansado? Debe dormir. (It's the truth. You are tired? You should sleep.)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Veramente, estoy ebrio. Debo dormir.

Comment: @EliSadoff Buenas noches. (Good night.)

Comment: If you speak the language and feel up to it, I would think that *translating* the question into English (via an edit) would also be appropriate. The only concern there is that the person who asked it may not understand the answers they receive. But they could use a translation service, and the answers would still be useful for others in the future.

Comment: @CodyGray That was addressed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/5021321) and the general advice was to not translate the post.

Comment: If you only post the comment in another language there is no way for anyone not knowing that language to know if the comment is offensive or not

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the non-English question cannot or will not be salvaged for any reason, do what you must to either direct the asker to the appropriate localized site, if one exists and the question is on-topic for the site, or direct the asker to either post in English or, if they cannot do that or the question really is unsalvageable for *any* site, find somewhere else to ask.

The question itself can be closed as usual. Either "unclear what you're asking" or some custom off-topic reason.