# Get a new flag for non-English posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, english

Flagging non-English posts right now requires different actions if it is a question or answer. A question should be flagged/vote to be closed as unclear. A answer should be flagged as `VLQ` or `NAA`.

Instead of doing this couldn't we just add a **This is not English** flag so it becomes obvious what to use?

Comment: @NathanOliver i know that that i can flag it as **unclear what you're asking** i suggest to add another flag, if that possible or not

Comment: I edited the queue to make it more a discussion on proposing a new flag and retracted my close vote.

Comment: And how often do you see such non-english posts? I see maybe a few per month and that isn't enough for a dedicated flag, at least in my opinion. "Unclear" and VLQ are enough for that.

Comment: We don't get nearly enough such posts to warrant a dedicated flag. Unclear covers those posts just fine.

Comment: I'd bet if you introduced this flag many of the more borderline non-native English speaker posts would be flagged with it…

Comment: Imo, if there is a tag. It become legal, and you don't want that!

Comment: Why do we need an additional flag?  You're already aware that existing flags are applicable, so why do we need any additional flags?

Comment: @Servy This is just a suggest nothing else if SO not want that then it is OK

Comment: @YCF_L And if you're going to make a suggestions, you need to justify why that suggestion is merited.  If you can't possibly come up with even a single reason for why this would be helpful, then you're just wasting people's time by even bringing it up, because apparently even you don't think that this would be helpful.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/4074148) *Questions written in non-English should be closed as unclear what you're asking. Answers written in non-English should be flagged as very low quality, although not an answer will generally be honoured too.  Comments written in non-English should be flagged using whatever flag feels suitable (likely, any of them except rude or offensive).*

Comment: I think it should be "This is not an English".

Comment: Funny how this got a score of -22 and now that this feature is implemented the meta announcement gets a score of +180

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer the needs of the community change over time. The newly implemented solution isn't a flag, doesn't work on answers, and therefore is entirely different from the feature that was suggested here

Comment: One thing that seems to have happened, speaking just anecdotally, is that as soon as "Stack Overflow in Portuguese" was created, people started posting questions in Portuguese on the English Stack Overflow.  They never used to much.  It only really became a problem once a solution for it was created.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think this occurs often enough to warrant a specific flag reason taking up space in the flag dialog.

Comment: this is not reason at all, if you click to **should be closed..** it will take you to another frame so, they can do it with the same logic

Comment: @ycf the close reason dialog? This place is just as tight. Either placement would also cause havoc on non-english sites.