# Introducing a new close reason specifically for non-English questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, english, announcement

As [was proposed and justified back in December](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422034/proposing-a-community-specific-closure-reason-for-non-english-content), the Stack Overflow moderators have [finally] rolled out a new close reason (under the "community-specific reason" category) for questions that are not written in English. In a revelation that we hope will not be too shocking, the new reason is called "**Not written in English**".

[image: Screenshot of close dialog, with the new "Not written in English" reason selected and outlined with a red-freehand circle.]

The guidance and other system messages associated with this close reason are exactly as shown in [the answer to the proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422035). These were composed collaboratively by the Stack Overflow moderators and given the nod of approval by a Community Manager (CM). We are pretty happy with them, and we think you will be, too. Unfortunately, once put into place, this text is not editable except by a CM, so we're not going to be entertaining [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) proposals for improvement; the time for that has passed.

The guidance was carefully designed to capture some important policies, like the fact that you should not close questions just because they happen to include some non-English variable names, error messages, or other short excerpts, and the fact that you should not translate questions to English for the author.

---

This new close reason is accompanied by a shiny new Help Center article: ["**Can I ask a question in a language other than English?**"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)

This Help Center article is linked in the guidance associated with the close reason, and, of course, it is available for anyone who actually looks in the Help Center to read. It is designed to serve multiple purposes:

- Clearly state that English is required for all content on Stack Overflow, especially questions.
- Explain why this decision has been made. (The decision is not new, but new users may not be aware, so it's good to have a central, official place for this information to exist.)
- Point users who are unable or unwilling to write in English to the localized versions of Stack Overflow. (This Help Center page is editable by moderators and we plan to keep it up-to-date if any other non-English versions of Stack Overflow are rolled out.)
- Provide reassurance for users who are willing to ask in English but aren't very good at writing it.
- Provide guidance for users who have failed to meet this requirement and thereby ended up having their question either closed or deleted.
- Repeat the part about being patient for TL;DR-ers.

If you have suggestions for improving this Help Center page, feel free to suggest them in the answer box below. As noted in a parenthetical above, Stack Overflow moderators can edit this specific page and can therefore make improvements/updates as needed.

As the astute readers will notice, we are still waiting for guidance blurbs from the moderator teams of *Stack Overflow em Português* and *Stack Overflow en español*. These have been requested and are presumably in the works. However, we didn't want to hold up the roll-out of the close reason waiting for these, since they can be added at any time.

---

The FAQ here on Meta, ["**How do I deal with non-English content?**"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673), has also been updated to reflect the existence of this new close reason. As it says there, we *strongly prefer* that you use this close reason for all questions that are not written in English. While you could plausibly continue to use either "needs details or clarity" or a custom reason, we see no reason why you would want to do so (except being unaware of a more appropriate reason, hence this announcement). The new reason provides better guidance and more actionable information for everyone: the prospective close-voter, the question author, and everyone else.

---

Go forth and use this close reason appropriately!
Questions, gripes, suggestions, and praise are all welcome as answers below.

Comment: Typo in the Help Center article, second paragraph: "enthusiast" -> "enthusiastic"

Comment: No, @Sabito; "enthusiast" is correct there. Stack Overflow's userbase includes both professional programmers and enthusiast programmers. Enthusiast means something subtly different from enthusiastic. The way it reads now, it means programmers who are not getting paid to write code but nevertheless are interested in and/or enjoy programming. If it said "enthusiastic programmers", it would imply that our users are enthusiastic, which is not necessarily the case. :-) Also, fun fact: that particular phrase is canned and inserted there via a variable; it also appears in the [tour].

Comment: Someone enthusiastic buys one model train and makes it go in a circle. An enthusiast buys 20 trains, occupies the entire attic with a massive track, buildings, trees, lakes, etc., spends at least 4 hours a day there, has a conductor hat and knows literally everything there is to know about trains, and invites people over to share that knowledge (and play with trains). I don't call it a subtle difference myself :)

Comment: Yet, hasn't your hypothetical enthusiast become enthusiastic, @Gimby? Stack Overflow still means to be a home for the person who is interested in programming, doesn't get paid for it, and is very-much-not-enthusiastic about it. (Disclaimer: The trees and lakes in my attic should not be taken to imply enthusiasm.)

Comment: Alright alright, I went one station too far with the analogy.

Comment: Does this addition use all of [so]'s custom close vote reasons now? Can't recall if "we" had 1 or 2 left prior to the addition of this new very welcome reason.

Comment: @Larnu With this addition, all 5 slots for site-specific close reasons are now filled on Stack Overflow. Combining the previously-separate "general computer usage" and "server administration" reasons together into a more generic (but also simultaneously more useful) "not programming or software development" reason freed up 1 slot, which this one now fills. It's almost like we planned it or something. :-)

Comment: @Gimby You certainly went off the rails with that one

Comment: Did I just cast the first close vote with this new reason? (Even if not the first, one of the first.)  Waiting impatiently for the next community-specific reason: _we don't do your homework_.

Comment: @davidbak No, I used it as a test before I ever posted this announcement, so you're definitely not the first; sorry. :-) And, uh, I don't know if you're joking about the next part, but we definitely aren't going to be adding a "we don't do your homework" close reason as that's never a valid reason to close a question. SO doesn't care whether the question is the user's homework. It only cares whether the question is on-topic, clear, of sufficiently narrow scope to be answered in our Q&A format, and contains all of the information required to answer it. (You see how those map to close reasons?)

Comment: the linked help article is massively helpful! +1

Comment: Yes Finally!!!!

Comment: This is practically useless.  Recently everytime I've entered such a close reason manually, everybody else vote "unclear" on the first modal screen instead.  I doubt that will change.

Comment: Are the close reason and the help center page displayed in the user's native language if available?

Comment: I didn't know moderators can add a close reason, I thought only staff could.

Comment: Not that I'm much active on SO, but read this topic, read the help page, and it seems like some priorities were misaligned. The page is really nice and well-written *English*. Do remember that it's targeting people who, usually, can barely speak the language. While it's been getting better, Google Translate is by no means perfect (eg it only got good enough to use with Polish in the past 3-5 years). Personally, I'd see the text be as simple as possible, without unnecessary flourishes.

Comment: @jaskij The bold first line ("English is required for all content on Stack Overflow") is about as simple as can be, isn't it? If you have concrete suggestions for improving the content, please post an answer below. Do remember that poorly-written or choppy English is often *less clear* to both non-native speakers and machine translation tools. If someone can't read English *at all*, then the Help Center page isn't really targeted at them. We have nothing for them here; all we can do is close their question.

Comment: @user253751 No. Nothing on this site is displayed in the user's native language. The site has no idea what the user's native language is, and even if it did, there is no localized text available. Stack Overflow is an English-only site. That applies to its questions and answers as well as its close reasons and help text.

Comment: @Dexygen The whole entire point of introducing this reason is to prevent people from voting to close as "unclear" (which is really a poor fit) and instead allow them to close for a *descriptive* reason. So, I really hope what you describe will no longer happen. It should be almost as easy to choose this reason as it is to choose the "unclear" reason. No typing will be necessary, which is, I presume, what used to slow you down.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, moderators can add new close reasons within certain limits. The only close reasons we can add/change are under the "A community-specific reason" category, and we only have a maximum of 5 slots available under that category. As I already noted in reply to Larnu, the addition of this reason fills all 5 slots that SO has under that category, so we can't add anything new. Changing any of the reasons *not* under the "community-specific reason" category requires a developer. Modifying the text for any of the existing reasons requires a CM (staff).

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't care about getting slowed down, because I wanted to apply the proper close reason.  Very few give a shit about a proper close reason, not even users who participate on meta i.e. using "too broad" when a question does NOT include mulltiple questions in one. -- I bring this up on meta all the time and get shit on.  This new initiative is just a giant waste of effort..

Comment: @Dexygen If you care about giving a proper close reason, why would think that this initiative is a giant waste of effort? Trying to get a proper close reason, with useful and relevant advice, has been the sole motivator for all moderators who have worked to make this happen. Your rejection/dismissal of it makes no sense to me. The issue of "too broad" (which has now been renamed to "needs more focus") being used when the question does not ask multiple questions is a different problem, one caused by a mistake when the company renamed that reason (they left out the rest of the explanation).

Comment: @Dexygen are you complaining just for the sake of complaining? Because your complaints really make no sense. You said you were manually writing basically the equivalent of this close reason. Well, you don't have to now. But you decided that's wasted effort, yet you typing the close text isn't? And you said you want to apply the correct close reason - now there is one that *exactly* matches, rather than the poorer fit "Unclear" which you also indicated wasn't as good. Yet you still maintain that it was a waste of effort to introduce a proper close reason. This seems like an XY complaint.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't consider it wasted effort to 1) click on community specific reason and then 2) type in a manual reason.  The real issue here is that almost everybody considers it wasted effort to even do #1 above -- they'd rather just enter "unclear", or "needs more focus" (when there are NOT multiple questions being asked)  The thing that's not ackowledged here is that users voting to close are just are arbitrary and careless as users posting closeable questions, and THAT is what makes this a waste of effort.  Solve that problem first, then maybe this is worthwhile.

Comment: BTW, this posts concludes with "gripes .... are welcome", but, as usual, not mine.  Typical meta bullshit.

Comment: @Dexygen It actually said that gripes are welcome "as *answers* below". You posted a comment, not an answer. And still, you're more than welcome to gripe. You'll note that I haven't deleted your comments or anything. It doesn't say that gripes won't be replied to. In fact, it kinda implies the opposite. You think it's "typical meta bullshit" that your gripes get read and individually replied to by a moderator? Well, that is the kind of service we strive to provide. You're welcome.

Comment: By the way, @Dexygen, before dismissing users who voted to close questions as "arbitrary and careless", you might want to know that [the official FAQ here on Meta for how to deal with non-English content](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/297680/revisions) actually advised users to raise a "needs details or clarity" on non-English questions before my most recent edits to it, updating it to reflect the existence of this new close reason. Now, I happen to agree with you that that wasn't really a good choice, but it wasn't my decision, and there *weren't* really any good choices. Now there are.

Comment: This should probably be its own question, but how do we deal with the commentators who redirect the person to one of the "foreign" stack overflows, when the question is terrible in any language? For example, someone posts a no-effort homework dump in Spanish. And someone else says "please take this to es.stackoverflow". I find that really inappropriate because the question is going to be just as unwelcome there, and it must be frustrating for the OP to be told to take their question somewhere, then have it closed. Can the mods please provide some guidance on dealing with this kind of question?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem such comments are no longer needed.

Comment: @KevinB The people who make such comments may not feel that way.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem it doesn't matter how they feel, just cast the flag.

Comment: Great to have a close reason. But why not go one step further and _warn_ users if they are writing in a non-allowed language to reduce the number of such questions in the first place? Here's my proposal: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422842/warn-the-user-if-they-are-writing-in-a-language-other-than-english

Comment: Good, I proposed this there are more than 5 years https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344485/get-a-new-flag-for-non-english-posts

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: Unfortunately, the folks who can't read a Spanish question are going to have limited ability to identify *bad* Spanish questions. I'm okay with pointing *all* such posters to the correct foreign language SO; at least the people who evaluate it there presumably have the knowledge to identify such bad posts.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I disagree completely.  My feeling is that if someone can't read Spanish well enough to tell whether the question is appropriate for es.stackoverflow.com, then they shouldn't redirect the user there.  Instead, they should just sit things out.  It's not compulsory to comment.  Likewise for Portuguese and Russian, of course.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Instead, they should cast a close vote. Even if you *can* read the question in the language it's in cast the close vote. there's no reason to do anything else now that we have a valid close reason for these cases.

Comment: Oh, I agree, @KevinB, but that doesn't mean that people won't make these (in my opinion incorrect) comments saying "you should ask this question on es.stackoverflow.com".  My question was how to deal with such commentators.

Comment: i think we're [going in circles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422751/introducing-a-new-close-reason-specifically-for-non-english-questions#comment944493_422751). Incorrect comments like that can just be flagged as no longer needed

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem All comments directing users to other sites should be flagged as "no longer needed" so that they can be removed. Same as any other comments that merely recapitulate the close reason. (Such comments are distressingly common in my experience. I don't know why so many people feel compelled to repost stuff that is already on the page in a much more visible way than their comment.)

Comment: @jaskij Your comment is worthy of a full meta question -- as a second release, could the English guidance start with (or start with a clear link to) a basic English version of the same thing?  After all, non-English writers may be basic English readers.

Comment: What about questions with English so bad it can't be understood?

Comment: @DannyVarod In case you are being serious: vote to close as _Unclear_. The suggestion that a poorly written question is not in the language it was intended to be written is not useful to anyone, not to mention an unnecessary insult to injury.

Comment: I usually edit to fix, but sometimes they are too unclear. Couldn't remember that option.

Comment: @DannyVarod My response would basically be what E_net4 said. This reason is only meant for questions that are not written in English. The whole reason we created it was to provide clear, relevant guidance. It should *not* be used on questions that are written in *poor* / unclear English, because it would provide the wrong guidance in those cases. If it is possible to edit and fix such questions, this is strongly preferred. If it is not possible, either because it is completely gibberish or there is some ambiguity, then you should vote to close as "needs details or clarity".

Answer (score 59):

Fantastic! Huge thanks to all moderators involved.

I am often encountering non English questions in the reopen queue that were updated trying to conform to the site rules, but are not translated in English.

Guidance for "Needs details or clarity" close reason was clearly lacking clear explanation that questions need to be written in English. We had to rely on leaving custom comments to guide people.

I hope that dedicated close reason will reduce number of such questions.

Of course, it would be better there is clear guidance when asking questions, so that such questions are not asked in the first place, but I'll take any improvement in the area.

Comment: For what it's worth, whenever I VTC'd for "clarity" on a non-English question, I'd post the following boilerplate, duplicated/googletranslated into the original language: "_The language of Stack Overflow is English. Please post your question in English, or with an English translation, if you wish to receive assistance here._" If it was in Japanese, Spanish, Portuguese, or Russian, I'd also provide a link to the appropriate other-language-SO.

Comment: Yes, playing "guess-the-language" (especially Portuguese vs. Spanish for non-speakers), using machine-translation tools to generate low-quality content, and posting of noisy comments are all *exactly* what we're trying to eliminate with this close reason.

Comment: Google Translate FTW to get what language it is. :)

Comment: @CodyGray Refer them to Stack Overflow eñ Portuñol.

Answer (score 22):

The bottom section in [the linked help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) says:

> #### I did what you said, but my question still hasn't been restored.
>
> As we said, please be patient! Everyone on this site—both moderators and reviewers—is a volunteer, and it takes time for the processes that we have in place to work. However, if you followed the instructions provided here, your question should eventually be reopened and/or undeleted.

This is misleading. It is likely that, after translating, the post is still not suitable for the site, and review should not reopen it.

Comment: Good point; thanks. When I wrote this, I was assuming that the issue would be a lack of any feedback. Once the question gets reviewed and a decision is made by reviewers, if it is not re-opened, that feedback should be made available, along with the specific reason chosen by the reviewers. But it's still worth mentioning this explicitly. I'll take a stab at the wording some time later. Suggestions welcome, of course!

Comment: In what way is it misleading? The last sentence?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, the question doesn’t need to be reopened just because they translated their post to English. Most first posters miss a lot of information in their post, or ask questions that are off topic.

Comment: Done, finally. I want to say that I took my time composing the perfect text, but, really, I just got busy and forgot. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I don't really approve of the text in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) that encourages people to try to salvage deleted questions. Very often, non-English questions have multiple problems and would be off-topic even if translated.

Scenario:

- Someone posts a non-English question which is also unclear, but you need to know their language as well as the technology in question to tell.
- 3 trusted users need to cast close votes.
- 3 trusted users also cast delete votes for some reason, most likely they considered the question not to be salvagable. Or maybe the closed question was simply deleted by Roomba.
- The OP returns and find their question close and deleted. They carefully read the help file (yeah, we'd wish... but in my scenario the OP is a exemplary new user). They translate the question then flag for moderator attention.
- A moderator gets involved and reviews the question. They can tell that the question is now in OK English and appears to be about programming and not too broad etc. The moderator restores it.
- Trusted users with domain knowledge, that the moderator happened to lack, note that the question should be closed because it is unclear.
- 3 trusted users cast close votes.
- The question is closed again.

Result:

- 3+3 trusted users (9 if counting delete voters) and 1 moderator had to be involved to get this bad question removed, salvaged, then removed again.
- The OP has followed the help file and also put in effort, except translation was not enough.
- The OP is now pissed off since their question was closed the second time.
- Everyone lose.

---

Instead, the help page should simply not mention possibly deleted questions at all. Also how to deal with deleted questions as the OP is not unique to non-English questions, so the text doesn't belong in this particular help file.

The OP should post an entirely new question. That way we minimize moderation workload. Yes, the old, bad question will count towards a question ban - tough luck.

Look at the pending work in the review queues: **we simply don't have the manpower to keep 7 people busy salvaging crap**, let alone spoon feed oblivious people who don't realize that the language used on the Internet as well as on SO is English. Veteran users could be doing far more meaningful moderation tasks such as suggested edit- or close vote reviews, flagging inappropriate content etc. And moderators shouldn't even need to be involved at all.

The required workload for salvaging this doesn't stand in proportion to how easy it is to post a bad question. The only one who should be putting in work to salvage the bad question is the one who posted it.

It is however reasonable not to cast delete votes on the question. The OP then has sufficient time to fix the question and put it in re-open review, or otherwise Roomba's eventually gonna get it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I largely agree with your points. We... discussed this *significantly* internally before settling on what we felt was the best policy. One of the most significant counter-arguments for the other side is that we don't want to essentially instruct users to re-post the same question after having it deleted. In many/most other contexts, that is considered abusive behavior, so even though it would arguably be correct behavior in this particular edge case of having posted the question in the wrong language, is it worth training users in wrong behavior?

Comment: @CodyGray Regardless, training new users what to do with their deleted posts is not text that belongs in the help file for non-English questions, since it is a broader topic that applies no matter why the question was closed.

Answer (score 10):

I do not have the time nor the energy to read all the past discussions on this topic, so I hope this has not already been mentioned.

I postulate that the major reason why people post questions on Stack Overflow in languages other than English is because they are momentarily / temporarily / absent-mindedly unaware of the fact that Stack Overflow is in fact in English.

You might ask, how can someone possibly be unaware of the fact that Stack Overflow is in English?

Browser-supported machine translation. That's how.

These folks are probably browsing Stack Overflow in their native language all day, so when the time comes to post a question, they don't realize that this web site is ***not*** in their native language.

(See, I try to see the good in people; I try to find explanations for their behavior that do not assume by default that they are just complete and utter retards.)

Thus, besides this new close reason, which is very welcome, an approach which might address the problem closer to its root is to do something to the "Ask a Question" page so that it either

- does not get machine-translated by web browsers, or
- detects machine translation and gives an appropriate message.

I have no idea how either of these things would be accomplished.

Comment: I mean, had you read other context, [you'd have found this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) which talks to much of your concern.  The tricky thing (and the thing that is unsolvable in general) is trying to put this verbiage for *every* language that someone wants to use the site in.

Comment: I fleshed out your thoughts re "detecting machine translation" into a feature request: [Warn users if they are asking in a language other than English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422842/warn-the-user-if-they-are-writing-in-a-language-other-than-english)

Comment: Re *"Browser-supported machine translation"*: That has always been suspected, but what is the actual configuration, feature and browser(s) that makes this possible? E.g., does [a feature like this make](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-translator-in-microsoft-edge-browser-4ad1c6cb-01a4-4227-be9d-a81e127fcb0b) it into transparent invisible output going out from the browser?

Comment: @PeterMortensen based on my experience, [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) also supports automatic language detection and translation to the whole page.

Comment: I live in The Netherlands, but I don't grok Dutch, so I use Chrome's translation feature a lot. When I ask it to translate a page, it always asks me if I want to translate just this one time, or to always translate pages in Dutch.  I have never tried the "always" option, but I suppose that if I ever said "always" then I would never see Dutch on the interwebz again forever.

Comment: @Makoto I read your link I and I don't see the connection between this answer post and the page you linked. Could you please help point out where it is?

Comment: @PeterMortensen In Chrome, if you view a page in a language other than one you speak, it will offer to translate once or always. If you tell it to always translate, when the page loads it will load with the original language momentarily and then translate automatically. Just so you know what the behaviour is.

Answer (score 5):

The link mentioned in the asker-facing help text links to https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions which still has TODO in the content for the Portuguese and Spanish help texts.

[image: TODO: mod-provided blurb here.]

Comment: I award +1 point for your astuteness in reading the Help Center page, but -1 point for your lack of astuteness in reading this announcement: *"As the astute readers will notice, we are still waiting for guidance blurbs from the moderator teams of* Stack Overflow em Português *and* Stack Overflow en español. *These have been requested and are presumably in the works. However, we didn't want to hold up the roll-out of the close reason waiting for these, since they can be added at any time."*

Comment: My attention to detail is extremely selective

Answer (score -7):

This message should be localized according to the user's [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header, as much as possible, to ensure the user understands it.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include translations of the message for all possible languages. Once you've done so, we'll be sure to request that staff implement this feature.

Comment: Somehow the user was able to both create an account (or login) and enter his question, which are all forms purely in English and not translated...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek often it *is* translated, by the browser, as pointed out by Mike Nakis.

Comment: @DanGetz Except the user knows it is seeing a translation and not original site. It is at least displayed, if not even after an explicit action from him to ask its browser to translate. And I am pretty sure that the help section clearly says that questions should be in english, so user HAS this information but decides on purpose not to follow it (or maybe thinks the browser is also translation by some miracle in the opposite direction?). So we are back to "users are not reading the documentation prior to asking a question", and it is not a language issue at all...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek it can be easy to forget. I'm not arguing for the questions to remain, or for translating anything. Just reminding that you can't count on an inability to read English to stop someone, because certain browsers (Chrome at least) push uncareful users in that direction.