# Correct action for a question originally in another language

Tags: discussion

What would the correct action to take for the following question?

[VBA string double substring error (Run-time error 424: Object Required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137180/vba-string-double-substring-error-laufzeitfehler-424-objekt-erforderlich)

It was originally asked in German, and received an answer in both German & English. There are also comments in German & English.

The question has since been translated, but there's also still plenty of German around. Should it have been translated?

My first thought was to flag it - perhaps *for moderator intervention*, but I'm usually reluctant to use that flag unless it's very obviously necessary. My second thought was to leave it, because in it's current state someone could find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't translate them, close them as "Unclear".

Generally, the OP will probably be unable to answer any questions (comments) about the question, if it's translated. He will likely also be unable to accept the right answer.

In the end, nobody is helped by having a semi-non-English Q/A on SO.

Comment: That's a really useful answer and dupe link, thanks. The only thing it doesn't cover is what to do when it's already been translated. It's going to be difficult to get it closed as unclear when people see a pretty clear question in the review queue. Roll back the edit?

Comment: Nah, leave it be, I guess... Maybe link the person that edited it, to [_"How do I deal with non-English content?"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)