# Is there a list of Stack Overflow sites in other languages?

Tags: feature-request, languages, portuguese-stack-overflow

Is there a list of "Stack Overflow in *(language)*" sites? (Not a list in other languages of SE sites, nor *(language)* usage SE sites.)

I mean, an official page that I can link to?

I searched, but the only results that came up were a couple of answers here in meta, all of them incomplete, some of them mentioning beta sites that have long since gone down. 
So unless I'm using the wrong search terms, such an official list doesn't exist, can that be right?

On a totally unrelated note, why does this meta site have a tag for [portuguese-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portuguese-stackoverflow), but not for any of the other ones, not even the original English one?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites ... just search for "stack overflow" there.

Comment: Hm. The thing is, I came upon a post by someone clearly having troubles with English, and I wanted to show him a list of what other languages SO comes in. The complete list of SE sites would only confuse the matter I'm afraid.

Comment: How bout this one? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297734/4099593

Comment: @BhargavRao Ah, that's a good one. As long as it will remain current - i.e. someone will need to update it manually as soon as the situation changes - it will be a good reference.

Comment: Yep. As it's made a community wiki (and is on the [faq]), I guess someone will maintain it.

Comment: @BhargavRao One question though. How come the Japanese site doesn't appear in the list Tom linked to? The list does contain beta sites, so that's not it.

Comment: @MrLister It's written in Japanese, so you can't use ctrl+f and search. Scroll down and look for a red stackoverflow symbol. That's the Japanese one.

Comment: Strange, I though I'd searched for スタック・オーバーフロー as well, but apparently not good enough. Oh well. Anyway, can you post that as an answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: @BhargavRao Huh. What about [this other answer](/a/349404/5764553)? It's prettier...

Comment: @AndrewMyers Sure, but that one was posted two weeks after BhargavRao's comment!

Comment: @MrLister Uggh... I keep opening active questions and forgetting to look at timestamps.

Comment: There seems to be a current effort to close Meta questions that even **mention** the Portuguese language version of Stack Overflow as off topic. Some of them are indeed off topic, but this one clearly is asking about the English language version of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Blackwood Oh. Do you mean if I edited the question to remove all mention of this, it would become eligible for reopening?

Comment: @MrLister You could give it a try.

Comment: https://ru.stackexchange.com https://pt.stackexchange.com https://ja.stackexchange.com https://es.stackexchange.com There is no more language because the SE won't really internationalize on cloudy reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where to find a **list of StackOverflow sites available in languages other than English**?

As pointed by the comments on the original question, there is no such list maintained automatically, but [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297734#297734) lists them and it would make sense to keep it up-to-date.

Other options:

- If a site has been launched, it should appear in the [*All Sites* list on StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic).
- If a site has been proposed by users, it should appear on [*Area51*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

But if a site is in beta and has been launched without going through Area51 first, then it's not listed by the above two options (the case of [jp.stackoverflow.com](https://jp.stackoverflow.com) at the time of writing.)

The best option then seems **to get a list of all subdomains of stackoverflow.com**. There are several ways to do so ([here are a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131989/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-subdomains-of-a-domain)), but the easiest one seems to use WolframAlpha:

**http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stackoverflow.com**

Vist the link then click on `Subdomains` › `More`. At the time of writing, this lists these foreign languages: [ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Moderator Cody Gray deleted the linked meta post on March 15 of this year. The meta-based list is no longer available to most users.