# How can I request a Stack Overflow site in a new language?

Tags: support, internationalization

I want to suggest the creation of a new Stack Overflow site in Persian. Should I make a proposal in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) or is there another way to do it?

How did the sites [for Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) and other languages begin?

Comment: Make a proposal on area51, as mentioned in an answer to the question: [Is there a list of Stack Overflow sites in other languages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348851/is-there-a-list-of-stack-overflow-sites-in-other-languages/355997#355997)

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting down voted, I wanted to make the proposal in `area51`, but I just thought maybe I should give it a second thought because maybe having a new language-specific, sub-site of stackoverflow.com, which is not a sub-domain of `stackexchange.com` like how `area51` itself is, Is something that should be discussed in somewhere within stackoverflow, and not in a subdomain of the parent website, stackexchange. I searched for simmilar questions but I couldn't find any. I also looked into some of the docs and couldn't find any mention of the point that would answer my q.

Comment: In case I'm getting down voted because the answer to my question was already mentioned in the question @DavyM refered to, I really don't think I'm supposed to be aware of every detail of every answer of every question that can somehow relate to my question. Obviously `Is there a list of Stack Overflow sites in other languages?` is a whole different question from `How to request a new stackoverflow site in a new language?`

Comment: It could be because this site's official name is "Stack Overflow". You know ... nit-picking ...

Comment: Voting on meta is different than on the main page. It shows agreements or disagreement with what you wrote. Maybe people just don't think that a person version is necessary.

Comment: @BDL firstly, If one does not agree with the creation of the persian version, they shouldn't down vote the question asking `How to request a new stackoverflow site in a new language?`, secondly. even if my question was a request to create a Persian version, it would be very silly to down vote it and basically disagree with it. IMHO such a request is not something to disagree with. it's just something to agree with and then the number of the people agreeing with it should be counted. Why on earth would one not like the existence of a Persian or any other language version of any site!

Comment: @BDL A new language is a new feature and is a great add to the system and would help so many people without hurting any. So basically disagreeing with it is disagreeing with the profit of some without any harm to others which IMHO only an inhuman person would be like this. In the other hand maybe someone would be like that they don't disagree with the Persian Version but they would prefer the resources(which actually here most of the resource is devoted to translation which is done by the community and there is no conflict of interest in that

Comment: @BDL because Persian version will be translated by the Persian people and Korean version by the Korean people which belong to different communities and there is little conflict here.) However, even if there was a conflict of resources here and the development of the Persian version would harm the development of say the Indian version again it would be very silly for the Persian people to down vote the request for Indian version and vise versa for the Indians. Because what makes the priority of creating a new Version is obviously not the reverse of haters! but the sum of lovers!

Comment: @aran BDL is telling you why it MAY be downvoted. Not that they downvoted you, or that if they did this is their reason. No need to argue with THEM :p. And for the "it's a benefit to EVERYONE".... hmmm.... no? By opening persian.StackExchange, there might be some questions that would have been posted on the English only SO that go to the persian one (for an ESL for instance). That robs everyone who goes to the English one of that potentially great question.

Comment: @BDL Therefore if one prefers the development of another Version instead of Persian version they shouldn't come and down vote the requests for Persian version. instead they should go and upvote for their own.

Comment: @Patrice I wasn't arguing with BDL personally I just thought maybe some people really did that so they should see my arguments. :D!;)!

Comment: @aran since your comments all start with "@BDL", this isn't the impression I was getting (@being a way to "answer" someone, it sure looks like you were talking straight to BDL). Fair enough though

Comment: @Patrice You are right. Actually I really liked your comment:D. But I just thought it would sound a little crazy if BDL mentions something and then I'm going to talk about that but not mention BDL! Actually I found his comment useful and I upvoted it. Do you think it's better if I edit my comments and remove the mention?

Comment: @usr2564301 I don't get your point. Would you be so kind to clarify it a little bit more?

Comment: Downvotes can be for *anything*. *Especially* on Meta.

Comment: Not really necessary to edit the comments (IMHO).

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree and I kinda feel it's a little unkind! today I saw a question with 52 down votes in one day! I totally disagreed with the author but I up voted it because I thought it was very unkind! IMHO He was just making a mistake and was not paying attention to a small point! Why so be cruel!? :D

Comment: The "meta" reason (no pun intended, read on) for this seemingly excessive nit-picking on Meta is because this is, quite literally, where the Standard is Set – or at least it gets *discussed*. If someone does a fairly reasonable request, but does not really care enough to spell the site name correctly ... well, as I said, nit-picking.

Comment: @usr2564301 Oh! are you referring to the fact that I wrote `stack overflow` instead of `stackoverflow`? lol! actually it was because I hadn't added the name of the site to my dictionary, thus I was getting a red line for it so you just let the computer fix it for me automatically! So it made it that way. Anyway, I believe you are lucky that there are no down votes for comments! otherwise you should have gotten tons of it bc the correct form appears to be `nitpicking`! not `nit-picking` :P ;)

Comment: I too find it disconcerting that a well-intentioned and honest question like this would receive a lot of downvotes. Having said that, in addition to what has been outlined in other comments, a downvote might simply mean "I have no interest in this" (and probably "if Stack Exchange are going to keep their payroll down, this is not something I think they should spend resources on", too, though that was already vaguely alluded at by other commenters).

Comment: Upvoted: I think the *question* has some merit (it is now the top result for me in Google for the query "how do I start a Stack Overflow in language X") and deserves a proper answer.

Comment: But arguing against the downvotes in a spree of comments is not good form here. There are many posts explaining voting on meta, and you are speculating about many things, and repeating very old arguments about others.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your comments. I'll keep them in mind. Do you think it's better if I delete that spree of comments?!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't.

If you post your proposal on Area 51, it will stay open only until a CM sees it and closes it with a formulation like "We do not currently accept proposals for sites in other languages. See [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition?noredirect=1&lq=1)"

---

Tangentially related: Stack Overflow the company used to have 4 people dedicated to running "SO in X". That number is down to 2 at present. So the projected trend is not up.