# Foreign language flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, flags

As stated in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/4746087) answer, SO requires English for questions, answers and comments. However, when flagging this kind of behavior, we can only choose between `spam`, `rude or abusive`, `should be closed`, `a duplicate`, `very low quality` or the custom `is in need of moderator intervention`.

I always use the last one to flag this kind of issues. But, shouldn't there exist an extra `foreign language` flag?

Comment: We use _unclear_ for these cases usually.

Comment: Why should there a specific flag just for this rare case? You don't know what OP is asking, because it is written in a different language, then it is unclear. So that flag is appropriate.

Comment: Do you see such questions so often that a special flag would be needed?

Comment: For answers, you can use the NAA or VLQ flag. Such answers don't deserve the extra penalties that come with "rude" or "spam" flags. And they don't require a diamond moderator's attention.

Comment: The answer you link to even states how you should flag those posts: *Questions written in non-English should be closed as unclear what you're asking*, and *Answers written in non-English should be flagged as very low quality, although not an answer will generally be honoured too.*

Comment: Actually, I flagged more foreign languages than i.e. spam or rude behavior.

Answer (score 32):

There is no need for a new flag. Foreign-language posts are not that prevalent, and existing flagging options suffice.

From the [FAQ post you link to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680):

> - Questions written in non-English should be closed as *unclear what you're asking*.
> - Answers written in non-English should be flagged as *very low quality*, although *not an answer* will generally be honoured too.
> - Comments written in non-English should be flagged using whatever flag feels suitable (likely, any of them except *rude or offensive*).

We'd only need a separate flag if existing options are not sufficient, for example when special handling is required. Foreign language posts do not require moderator intervention, are not so numerous and problematic that we need give the community special powers to remove them, or any other special handling. The existing options are just fine.