# How should we handle rude answers posted in a foreign language?

Tags: discussion, flags, rules

Had a minor debate in chat about a rude statement posted in German (not linking it since the user reposted it after having it dealt with, which validated the second one being removed as rude/abusive). There's two mandates here

1. [Flag foreign language posts as VLQ/NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350814/foreign-language-flag/350817#350817)
2. Flag rude things as rude

The question here is does #1 **always** override #2? My general view is that if it's foreign, I just VLQ it and move on (it's not worth the time to pull up Google translate most of the time). In this instance, though, several users fluent in German saw it and recognized it as rude.

Should we flag as rude if we understand it to be rude, or just leave it to the VLQ? If we're in chat (where enough rude votes removes it without a mod), does that change anything?

Comment: Would the moderator responding to your flag recognise the answer as rude?

Comment: @yannis Hence the question. If we can rude flag it out of the system directly, should we? I don't expect mods to speak all languages

Comment: Whatever you do, do not pull up Google translate. FWIW, after feeding your question through Google translate back & forth, this is what Google thinks of your sentence "(not linking it since the user reposted it after having it dealt with, which validated the second one being removed as rude/abusive)" -> `(do not link it since the user reposted it after processing it and validated the other that was removed as rude / addictive)`

Comment: As me being the root cause of this meta post: I flagged the answer first as VLQ, as per mod instruction then checked the translation. As I wasn't sure if that was rude I asked a native German speaker to verify. Their call was that the post was rude without doubt which made  me report the post to Smokey so the post would get more eyes on it in a short time and have the user watched. I forgot that the users following up on the SmokeDetector report would have to go through the same hassle I went through to verify if the post was abusive or not. I could have done that better, in hindsight.

Comment: [ the sound of people rushing to the socvr transcript ]

Comment: You can't handle the problem, neither can anyone else who isn't a mod. A flag is the only action that makes sense. If you are unsure of which flag it fits under, there's a custom one.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier they are all welcome ...

Comment: We should get rid of ALL the bad language.  We could start by burninating the PHP tag.

Comment: @Lundin Not really sure what you're getting at; though the text was butchered it's still presents the idea pretty clearly. Further, rudeness *typically* includes curses, which the translator has no issue with.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Such a situation would merit a custom flag.  You'd want to explain to the moderator that the content means something rude in another language, perhaps linking a translation.

The post *merits* the more severe penalty associated with an "offensive" flag, but odds are pretty high that most users that see the post (even including a moderator, if they only see an "offensive" flag without any additional context) won't understand the language, and so won't recognize it as offensive, they'll simply flag it as they would any non-offensive post in another language, rather than as offensive (which is entirely appropriate for them if they don't speak the language).  In such a case the post could well end up being deleted *without* being marked as offensive.  If you use a mod flag the mod will be able to mark the post as offensive, ensuring the appropriate side effects take place.

Comment: Good points. I prefer to avoid custom mod flags, though. The diamond moderators are busy enough as it is.

Comment: @S.L.Barth A situation like this *merits* the custom flag though.  Odds are *quite* high of an inappropriate result if you don't use a custom flag, and the situation is not sufficiently obvious on it's face that it merits the additional context that can be provided with a custom flag.  Mods are *constantly* telling people to use custom flags when the reason for a flag requires additional context, instead of being immediately obvious only looking at the post.  Besides, it's not like this happens so often that it's beyond the moderator's ability to deal with it; issues like this are rare.

Comment: @S.L.Barth A custom mod flag is also likely worthwhile simply because if a user is posting abusive content in another language it's probably worth taking a look at their other contributions for other similar behavior; they may have other content deleted as VLQ that was *actually* offensive, but not recognized as such due to being in another language.

Comment: @S.L. Barth: This is the sort of stuff that is meant for us to deal with. If you'd rather let the abusive content fester...

Comment: Good points (again). Normally, I'd provide extra context in the form of a comment on the post, so reviewers can see what's going on. When a user is already being rude, though, that's just going to make things worse.

Comment: @BoltClock I'd have flagged such cases as rude/offensive, but I'll be glad to use a custom mod flag instead.

Comment: @S.L.Barth There are a few problems there, one, a mod is less likely to see a comment than they are a custom mod message, two (and probably more importantly) posting a comment is making you a target to an abusive user; you don't want to be interacting with such a user in a situation like this as you're likely to escalate their behavior (by calling them out on it) and also to direct their malice towards you.

Comment: @Servy I'd use a comment if I were using a normal flag, as a signal to reviewers. I think we already agree that commenting on an abusive post is just going to make things worse.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Hence why I suggest a custom mod flag.  If you use a normal flag it pretty much forces you to comment to provide the context, and *that's a problem*.  Since it's important to not comment on such a post, the appropriate means of providing the context to the moderator is to use a custom flag.

Comment: @S.L.Barth But do we even know if/when moderators can see comments in their review queues? Whether we can see comments in review depends on the specific queue we're looking at.

Comment: @BSMP The moment we use a custom mod flag, we should put the context in the custom mod flag. Comments to clarify context are only needed when using regular flags. (i.e. for things that the community can handle, without involving a diamond moderator).

Answer (score 27):

Flag it as rude/offensive.

Being rude carries an extra penalty. We can forgive (new) users for posting in their own language; this can be attributed to ignorance.
But rudeness cannot be attributed to ignorance, it is malice by definition.

We don't want people to be rude here, regardless of the language.

Comment: I would also add a comment to clarify that it *is* rude for people/mods who don't understand the language.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That would be a brave thing to do. It would be the right action, but would also open  you up to retaliatory action from the poster. Since the poster is already upset.

Answer (score 14):

If I can feed the post into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) and be reasonably confident the user is being rude/abusive or spamming, I will flag as such.  That kind of behavior needs to be stopped right away and spam/rude/abusive flags facilitate that.  If I'm not sure what they are saying even after translation then I fall back to VLQ as that is what it is for.

Just because nuke-able content is in a foreign language does not mean it should not be nuked.

Comment: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) is great! "If I can feed the translation contribution from Google and be fairly safe, the user will be rude, addicted or unwanted, and I will classify it as such. This type of behavior should stop immediately and unwanted / rude / abusive messages make it easier. If I'm not sure what to sew after translation, I will come back to split because this is what it is."

Comment: @Lundin And?  Doesn't look like spam, rude, or abbusive so it gets a VLQ flag.

Comment: My point is, somebody could ask a question about operator overloading in C++ and Google Translate will turn it into a rude insult about your mother. So let us not use or recommend this "tool" for any purpose.

Comment: @Lundin You find me that and I'll believe you.  It works pretty well for me and I have never had a flag overturned because I got a bad translation.

Comment: Read my first comment again, please. If that doesn't prove that Google Translate is completely unreliable, then I don't know what does.

Comment: @Lundin even if google do a "best effort" translation, the difference between a normal post in foreign language and a rude/spam post is usually more then visibile, [example](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Siete%20un%20branco%20di%20scemi%20e%20dovete%20morire!) and you can test with some common offensive phrases in your own language, so yeah that Italian text with that translation I flag as rude (and maybe I leave a comment under post for mods)

Comment: it is reliable, not perfect though. Aniway I guess google translate is just good to be a independant check about what the one that flag the comment said. I don't think lot of people take the time to go translate a comment, eiither they will flag it or they will pass it.

Answer (score 2):

It's both R/A and VLQ. In such cases, it's better to flag it as Rude/Abusive and add a comment explaining that the translation is rude so that whoever handles the flag isn't confused by it. The penalties for rude content are (rightly) much higher than the penalties for VLQ content; if someone is posting such content, it should be handled accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure if you should expose yourself in a comment when you already know that op is rude.