# Where is SO's (or SE's?) policy on English Only?

Tags: support, english

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/9513577) has two answers, both of which claim that Stack Overflow requires English, which corresponds with my memory of reading such a policy. I've spent a good 10 minutes looking, and I can't find it anymore!

I'd have expected it to be in the help section, or explicitly referenced in [What type of questions should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) or [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (or even in one of the answers to the question linked above) But it doesn't seem to be there.

Has this policy been retired? The community seems to still treat non-English content the same way...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't recall the Help Center ever stating specifically that English is *required.*  Nevertheless, that is how the site got started, that's how the community views the way the site works, and that's the policy the moderators enforce.

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of this?  https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do believe I was! Thanks. Put it in an answer?

Comment: The canonical FAQ is [here on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). I'd forgotten we had one here on MSO, too.

Comment: @KevinB That's an answer! Post it (and add some brief quotations) so you can get upvoted. ;)

Comment: If applying some common sense: what language do you expect such a policy to be written in, if English isn't the required language?

Comment: @Lundin R'lyehian?

Comment: @Lundin Some sites allow users to post in any language that they desire.  For moderated sites, like StackOverflow, it's necessary for the moderators to be able to understand any language that is allowed.  But the fact that StackOverflow has explicit moderation may not be immediately obvious to a newcomer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**The clearest announcement of the official policy is the following post on the Stack Overflow Blog: [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)**. This was posted by Jeff Atwood in the early days of Stack Overflow. Jeff was one of the two primary founders of this site (although he has since left the company to pursue other projects).

Note, of course, that English-only was the policy since the very beginning. The policy wasn't created in 2009, just formally announced in a linkable document.

**There is also a canonical [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on the global Meta: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)** This is the one that I typically link to when leaving a comment. Questions with the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on Meta sites are *de facto* official policy. That tag is a "special" one that can only be applied by moderators, and we don't apply it unless the answers are an accurate reflection of site policy.

**Stack Overflow's dedicated Meta site (this one) also has its own [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) Q&A about this: [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)** Again, as I stated above, this ***is*** the statement of official policy. If it was incorrect, a moderator or a community member familiar with the policies of this site would fix it by editing.

The **Help Center** doesn't have any *specific* text that says "English is required; no other languages are permitted". I suspect this is because a lot of the Help Center text is globally maintained, and re-used on all of the Stack Exchange sites, some of which actually do allow non-English questions (in particular, the foreign-language versions of Stack Overflow).

However, a couple of pages in the Help Center do hint at English being required. In particular, the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page says:

> Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.

Unfortunately, this comes within a section talking about how to write a title, so someone could conceivably argue that we only require English in titles.

There's also the Help Center article [describing the quality filter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error), which lists

> Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

as one of the requirements for a question. The quality filter has certain heuristics that check for minimally acceptable usage of English spelling and grammar. Again, though, this isn't a very clear statement.

I would recommend not trying to point people to the Help Center for confirmation of this policy, but rather to one or the other of the canonical Meta FAQs. Or, you know, ask them to look around and follow what *everyone else* does when posting on this site.

If you don't want to bother reading all of the above-linked documents, I can quickly summarize why we require English: this site, like all sites in the Stack Exchange network, is moderated for content. **In order to ensure that such moderation can take place, it is necessary that we settle on a single, common language that is spoken by all community members and moderators.** English was chosen as that language, albeit not completely arbitrarily, given its status as a sort of global *lingua franca*, and *especially* so in the STEM fields.