# What's the best way to flag a comment that's not in English?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, languages

I recently flagged this comment:

[image: comment that's not in English]

I selected "Something else." and typed "It's not in English."

Is this the correct way to flag a comment like this? Is there a better way?

Something that worries me more: If this person only speaks in a language other than English, how could he/she have gotten enough reputation to comment?

Comment: It doesn't *really* matter, as long as you flag it. But "no longer needed" is simpler and easier, so it's what [we officially recommend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content).

Comment: I saw that. I must have overlooked the comment section of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What action do you expect a moderator to take besides deleting the comment? What use would a custom flag serve?

Just flag as *“No longer needed”*, and move on.

The user likely knows English as well. Possibly they just recognized that the post owner was from a Spanish speaking country and decided to comment in that language. Still, the only reasonable action is to flag the comment for deletion.

Comment: The content (when translated) was relevant to the question.

Comment: So? What do you expect a moderator to do about it?

Comment: I know this is unrealistic, but ideally there would be some auto-translate button they could push on a post to translate it to English.

Comment: That’s not what moderators do nor should do. Content posted in a language different than the site’s is to be deleted. You can post an appropriate comment in English if you want.