# I flagged this non-English answer as NAA. Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer, english

I [flagged this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926880/scaledrone-basic-chat-doesnt-show-messages/57657450#57657450) non-English answer as NAA (not an answer).

Why was my flag declined?

[image]

It is not a duplicate from this question (*[How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673)*), because although the FAQ says these posts should be flagged for deletion, this specific flag was declined by a moderator.

Comment: Relative meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553, so first one says to flag non english as VLQ/NAA and in any case if you decided to translate against direction in first meta, it's still NAA according to official guidance (second meta). Mods seems to be miss clicking a lot lately :)

Comment: BTW, what Robert says in comments is correct. Even in spanish, it's a "me too" comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)

Comment: see also [September 2011 Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/) of SE Community Moderator Blog: "Marking a flag `[declined]` was designed to deter serial abusers of the flagging system, but we find that this “slap on the wrist” is being used more often than is beneficial... try to err on the side of clearing as `[helpful]` whenever the user is trying to be genuinely helpful, _even if you do not necessarily act on the flag_...

Comment: Not only is it in the wrong language, it's not an answer. It says "I have followed the same tutorial and have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This was a trivially correct flag and should not have been declined.

The fact that it was not in English would have been grounds enough to mark the flag helpful and delete the post; the fact that even the translation is NAA just adds insult to injury.

Comment: Since declining the flag was a wrong action it would be nice if the mod that declined it would change the affected flags from `declined` to `disputed`. (Sorry to bother you, @BaummitAugen, but said mod hasn't an answer or comment here to ping them directly).

Comment: @ThomasSchremser I'm afraid that only works for red flags.