# What happens when I mark a question as VLQ in the "Help and Improvement" queue?

Tags: support, bug, help-improvement

I keep seeing the same questions repeatedly on this queue. This one was posted in Russian and I already flagged it as VLQ twice. Am I doing something wrong? What should I be doing instead of marking VLQ? There is not other obvious action from that interface.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/24056046

Comment: You should flag these as "unclear what you're asking", not "very low quality".

Comment: @JL2210 There's no option to VTC (and choose a close reason) directly from the H+I queue, though, "question is very low quality" is the only related link *directly* on the queue page

Comment: I never see that. All I see is "Edit" and "Skip", neither of which are appropriate.

Comment: @JL2210 https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0EfF.png IIRC it kicks the task out of the H+I queue and puts it back into Triage (hopefully no one presses "Requires Editing" in Triage again...)

Comment: The very low quality link is on the right hand side around the middle, it's not a button. It does appear to not be working, I've had the same question appear in my help and improvement feed 3 times today, despite clicking the low quality link

Comment: all users who kicked this question out of [triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24055512) would better get a [meta-tag:review-suspension]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel a question needs other actions taken than what the review queue you're in offers in its interface, you can click *on the question title* to open the question in the normal Q&A interface. From there, you can use the usual flag/close links to assign a close reason.

In the meantime, the question has been closed as off-topic.

Comment: That's another problem. When I saw this question in triage, I didn't see any available option. VLQ was not available and the flag options [don't seem to apply](https://i.imgur.com/jJPy0d3.png).

Comment: @giusti you needed to pick [Flagging > Closing > Unclear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/839601)