# Are solutions in comments frowned upon?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, someone posted a non-English question to regular SO. The solution ended up being easy enough, they needed to print using `%f` instead of `%d`. I offered some code in a comment to the question while echoing another comment's suggestion to visit the appropriate SO site for their language in the future.

Other high-rep users then proceeded to jump down my throat for offering solutions in comments, and "encouraging" non-English on SO. "I should have known better", "I don't know what you're saying (and am apparently incapable of using context clues)", "Don't encourage this behavior", "Don't offer solutions in comments", etc.

I was a bit miffed, to say the least. The question took forever to close (I would have voted to close, but can't yet), and in the meantime, people just kept piling on, acting like comment upvotes matter.

So, the main one here was "Don't offer solutions in comments". I wasn't going to offer a proper answer because they needed to know to post on the correct site. At the same time, it was a trivial problem that could have been closed as a typo instead of unclear. So, I wanted to just get them on their way armed with the knowledge of using the correct site next time, and a comment seemed the best way to do that.

I log in this morning, and lo and behold, ~50% of the questions I'm looking at have solutions in the comments (just like the questions I've been looking at for the last few weeks since trying to be active), but are lacking the same kind of brigade I went up against. Let's clear something up, my code in a comment was not an outlier, at least in `c++`. But because I happened to be able to communicate with someone in a foreign language, it's a "serious problem".

Did I just get a bad batch of high-point power-trippers? I don't care too much about getting called out on a bad practice, but the complete lack of consistency. As in I have looked at a fair amount of questions, but the only one where a solution in comments is taboo is when the question isn't English? Come on. That's ridiculously, incredibly hypocritical, and borderline xenophobic.

EDIT: The suggested dupe is not correct. It was not an off-topic question. It was a valid C++ question. It just happened to not be posted in English.

Comment: That leads into a separate discussion on how the question should be marked. It was NOT off-topic. It was a legitimate C++ question. There needs to a clear distinction when the only thing wrong is the language spoken by OP, with an easy re-direct to the correct SO site. Even the description of the unclear tag (how the question I'm referring to was marked) is nebulous.

Comment: [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)

Comment: That link reinforces what I commented earlier. "very low quality" or "not an answer" just because it's in a foreign language? That's BS. As was made abundantly clear, the big reason is people not knowing what's being said. But that cuts both ways. You don't know it's a "very low quality" answer or question if you can't speak the language. There simply needs to be a "wrong language" reason with easy re-directs to the correct language. I bet it wouldn't even be too tough to just move the question.

Comment: @sweenish: The concern is also that op would not understand an English answer anyway. There is also no problem with leaving a comment linking to the appropriate page (maybe even in op's language if you're able to write it). Specific redirects would only work for languages where a language SO exists though. You can also flag for moderator attention and request a migration.

Comment: And now you're side-stepping my actual question.

Comment: A post that is not in English, posted to an English-only site, is not understandable. A question that is not understandable is of low quality.

Comment: Question migration is not an easy thing and can cause confusion. Unless people are 100% sure and it's a migration that needs to happen often, they tend to not allow the question migration. If you feel the need is there, then feel free to raise a feature request in the meta and the community will vote on if they feel it's a worthwhile. There is always inconsistency between what some people say and others do, not everyone is up to date on how the rules work or what's best practice. Answers in comments are frowned upon because comments are often likely to disappear. It won't help future readers.

Comment: About the edit: A question in any other language than English **is** off-topic on SO. No matter what it talks about or how good the quality of the question is in that language. It might be a good question somewhere else (ru.SO, es.SO, pt.SO) but not on SO.

Comment: A question not in English is, by definition, off-topic.  It can't both be valid and not in English.

Comment: It helps your case here when you start watching your mouth (hands). Edit comments like "BS dupe" and the addition to your question title are neither helpful nor useful.

Comment: Except I understood it? I get the majority rule thing, but people here are latching on to the wrong topics. Here's what I want: either all these high point people legitimately crack down on answers in comments, or explain why this one in particular was so much worse.

Comment: @Tom, the original edit to change my title was neither helpful nor useful, and grammatically incorrect. The suggested dupe is BS. It's nowhere near what I'm asking. Reading my question would have told anyone that much. I also think higher-ups need to consider their definitions better. The question was NOT off-topic. That's probably the worst choice.

Comment: Look, what sort of response are you expecting to get, here?  Are you trying to get clarification on the current policy, change it, rail against it, or what?  Your actions are counterproductive for any meaningful action to be taken; you're just hardening resistance against your stance.  You can argue against the duplicate if you want, but calling it BS isn't going to do anything but ensure those that disagree vote to close it.

Comment: Yes, they are frowned upon.

Comment: I don't flag questions as off-topic or unclear because I'm unfamiliar with the library or specific principle being asked. In the same vein I don't go after answers because they use code with which I'm unfamiliar. Maybe I should start brigading comments that offer solutions in comments, though. What I'm learning is that SO flags are severely deficient in at least one key area. And we enforce violations to the extreme when people talk differently.

Comment: @TylerH but only when the OP speaks a different language, in my experience. Because I see it on the daily, as do the same people who brigaded my post.

Comment: @sweenish It's unclear to me what you're referring to re: language. My comment is purely in response to the title of this question. Comments are **not** for answers, no matter who tells you otherwise.

Comment: @fbueckert An actual answer to the question I asked. Not an unrelated dupe and people just parroting broken definitions at me. If answers in comments are verboten, why do I see it every single day, just as often as not? Why did people decide it was super unacceptable just because OP wasn't speaking English? Because that was the only differentiator.

Comment: Then...maybe lay off the charged language?  You're arguing with everyone who's trying to tell you how SO works, and you're ignoring and challenging it.  Nobody's going to attempt to help or answer your specific question if you ignore what everyone's already telling you.

Comment: The thing is I have heard these definitions. I very clearly disagreed with them early on. But all that's happening is people repeating them. Should I just circle back and keep re-posting my disagreement as well? I'm also very clearly saying that how SO works is broken in a very specific case. And it's very clear that people have no interest in making any kind of change. So I'll just bury the issue. But I will certainly think less of this site every time someone isn't brigaded for putting a solution in comments. Because we only care when OP doesn't speak English. That's my takeaway.

Comment: I was posting a detailed answer to your question, but it got closed.  Oh, well.

Comment: Well, making that change requires an open mind that, perhaps, the system isn't actually broken?  You don't have to agree with the policy provided, but it doesn't help to just say you disagree with it; it essentially writes off any argument to the contrary and doesn't show a willingness to engage with disagreement, and perhaps be willing to change your mind.

Comment: I'd have been willing if the explanations were more than just repeating the definitions I disagree with. If you present nothing new to me, what is there to be open about?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would still be interested to read your answer if it makes sense as a wiki or edit to existing wiki.

Comment: If you're unwilling to accept what already exists...why should anyone pay any mind to your disagreement?  It's a circular argument that nothing productive happens.  With that, I'm also done.  A conversation requires people talking *to* each other, not *at* each other.

Comment: @sweenish: The short answer is that comments are for clarification about a post's on-topic subject matter.  That is their only sanctioned use.  Any other use subjects them to removal, including posting answers in comments.

Comment: @fbueckert Your question is broken. How can I have a disagreement and be accepting of the thing I disagree with? Things don't improve when everyone blindly agrees with what's established. Disagreements and challenges drive change, not thinking it's working just fine. Definition parroting also fits into the definition of talking *at* each other, please don't pretend I'm the only one at fault here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And I try to adhere to that. I can eat my flub because at the end of the day I saw an opportunity to help since I happened to speak their language. I was here more about the wild overreaction I received to a daily thing, where the only differentiating factor was a non-English question. Mods either care about this or they don't. They shouldn't selectively care a whole bunch just because the question wasn't English. That doesn't paint a good picture. And SO's flagging system needs something specific to foreign languages because the flags as they exist now aren't adequate.

Comment: To clarify, no moderators were involved with [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58492168), except for deleting the comments in response to flags on them. The flagging system is perfectly adequate. Posts written in languages other than English can be flagged for literally *any* reason, including "very low quality" or "needs to be closed". The issue is not whether you should provide solutions in comments (you really shouldn't, but you aren't going to get into trouble for posting on-topic comments). What you shouldn't do is post anything that is not in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was NOT a legitimate question, even if it was in English. Your suggested answer of "use %f" would fall under simple typographical error, which is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

If you seen an answer in the comments on a simple question like that, that's usually what it is. You *shouldn't* answer (as in, in the "your answer" box) questions that are going to be closed/deleted, but I think there's some leeway in the "simple typographical error" to answer in the comments because it's a nice thing to do for the OP. The OP should then delete their post (in "shame"). And if they don't, it'll get closed/deleted as OT.

Because the question is not in English, though, it should have been closed for that reason alone. Doesn't matter if you understood it. Doesn't matter if someone google translated it so you COULD read it. The OP might have follow up questions which you/others can't answer and the question isn't helpful for other users who don't speak their language. Just don't touch it.

Comment: OMFG.  I get blocked from answering, and you can answer under the wire.  WHEN IS STACK EXCHANGE GOING TO FIX THIS BUG??!!!

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that. I saw you said it was closed, but somehow i could still answer (and thought maybe it was re-opened), so i just went for it.

Comment: yhyrcanus, there is a grace period which allows you to post an answer when you started writing the  before if was closed. That feature just doesn't work at any time.

Comment: Your second paragraph is the thing here. I didn't formally answer. I [eventually] corrected the typo in a comment, and according to the group that came after me, they don't see the same leeway you do. So what is it? Do we only care when OP speaks a different language? All I wanted to do was get them on their way and repeat a sentiment to visit the correct site next time. But I get the nth degree because OP wasn't in English, but the same thing happens literally all the time when it's English. So, how much do we really care? It's not a good look for SO.

Comment: Selected and +1. That leeway is what I thought was acceptable when I dropped my comments on that question, but some people feel strongly in the other way only when OP doesn't speak English, it seems.