# ♦-intervention flags for migrating OK-looking foreign language questions posted here

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons, languages

Today I encountered two foreign-language questions, both of them *looking* acceptable, but are posted in this English-language site rather than their respective foreign-language StackOverflow sites.

1. [Erro no envio de formulário Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415132/erro-no-envio-de-formul%c3%a1rio-ajax) [Portuguese]
2. [Plugins jQuery en Angular sin npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414466/plugins-jquery-en-angular-sin-npm) [Spanish]

At that time, I am neither proficient in Spanish nor Portuguese; and I also have to consider moderators which aren't proficient in these languages as well.

The first question, which is Portuguese [notice the ã] is about an Ajax and UTF-8 error involving an IllegalArgumentException, and contains four code parts each representing a part of his code. This one hasn't been negatively received yet.

The second one, which is Spanish [notice the *el*, *la* topics, and the *y*], is probably about JQuery and Angular, and how to use NPM to add JQuery in Angular. At the time of posting it is at -1.

I have flagged these posts as off-topic or unclear because they are foreign-language. Is it better to fire a custom diamond-intervention flag, stating that this foreign-language post either has to be closed or migrated if the foreign-language site exists, or just flag/vote for closure?

[Update: Not recommended to custom flag; the odds are known to be very low. See the community wiki question, [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content]) ]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We only migrate questions when we are confident that they are well asked and would be well-received on the target site.

Since, as you said, there is no guarantee that moderators are fluent in languages other than English, it would not be appropriate to ask moderators to migrate questions asked in these languages.

Put yourself in the destination site's shoes: would you want gibberish or off-topic questions migrated here merely because they appeared to be asked in English? I certainly wouldn't. We should treat other sites how we want to be treated.

The standing policy for dealing with questions written in a language other than English is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content). In short, you should recommend that it be closed as "unclear" or "off topic" (I use a custom off-topic reason, allowing me to explain the English-only rule that exists on this site). It is further stipulated that you not try to translate questions, even when you believe you can understand them, as you cannot be assured that the original asker can understand English, which would mean that they cannot interact with the question going forward in any meaningful capacity.

If you want to leave a comment *suggesting* that the person ask their question on another Stack Exchange site focused on a language other than English, then you are, of course, welcome to do so. If you are not absolutely certain of the quality and topicality of the question, I would ask that you point the user to the site's Help Center so that they can determine for themselves whether or not their question would be suitable there.

A custom moderator flag is not needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks. It looks resolved [and closed by 3 ordinary users]. Is firing a custom flag to deal with this issue more recommended than a recommend-closure flag [I am not 3K at that time], since it obviously looks out-of-place?

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩᛗ It isn't necessary to raise a custom flag just because a question is not in English; one of the standard "recommend closure" flags is fine. Of course, don't recommend closure of spam or abusive content. Those should be dealt with urgently, and there are special flags for them.

Comment: Ouf ot the 1200-strong post flags I've raised only 2 are ♦intervention flags, and only one is successful. The declined one still involved an action as it is deleted anyhow [which is what I've intended] and the successful one is the very first flag I've raised when I made my [incomplete first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625536/my-incomplete-first-post-create-gif-from-vanilla-java) in this site.

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩᛗ Yes, you had a ♦ intervention flag declined about 1.5 years ago, where you were asking for migration of a question to another site. That question was in English, but the moderator who reviewed your flag didn't think that the question would be well-received on the destination site. We are actually quite reluctant to migrate questions. You are welcome to use these flags to ask, but understand that odds are good they will be declined, unless it is obvious to us moderators that the question is quite good. Overall, there's nothing wrong with your flagging history.

Comment: I'm just wondering, how rare are migrations in overall, such as in terms of *posts migrated/day*? Have there been cases where a foreign-language post has been successfully migrated; and if so, how rare?

Comment: Migrations are quite rare. In the past 90 days, only 591 questions have been migrated to other sites. Most of those were done by regular users with close-vote privileges, to one of the 5 "unlocked" destinations (Meta, Stats, DBA, SU, Tex). Where ♦ mods were involved in migrating to "restricted" sites, this has only happened 59 times in the past 90 days. Code Review is the most popular target site, having 12 Qs migrated there, with an 8% rejection rate (closed by CR users after migration). Next most popular are Security and CS, with 8 questions migrated, ~10% rejection. Other sites are all < 5.

Comment: Thinking about this logically, it is quite rare that someone is going to manage to ask a high-quality question, but do so on the wrong site. Conscientious users who ask good questions suitable for migration don't need to have their questions migrated, because they'll make sure they ask on the correct site. Migration is really only there as an escape hatch, and in most cases, it makes more sense to delete and re-ask the question. The only time it really even makes sense to migrate is when there are good answers you want to save.

Comment: . Also, for sub-3K users, users can *flag* migrant-candidate posts to one of the five unlocked sites and if the migrant-candidate belongs to some other site, users can use a ♦-intervention flag. How often are (1) migration flags and (2) migration-like ♦-intervention flags raised, and what percentage of them are declined? [an approx is good enough]

Comment: @CodyGray It seems that you are against question migration. Do you agree with this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285472/313443 I was thinking about proposing removal of migration system as it is not serving any meaningful purpose (in my opinion). But I am still sitting on that idea and trying to gather more opinions.

Comment: @Dalija I'm not against question migration. I *do* migrate some Qs. I migrated [one asked on Meta (!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392315) just minutes before this one. That said, I largely agree with ChrisF's MSE answer. The migration feature just doesn't work, for a variety of reasons, including the realities of bad questions and mods not being experts on other sites' scopes. I don't think it should be removed as a mod privilege (migrating things between Meta sites is, at least, useful and important), but it should probably be considered for removal as a user feature and deemphasized.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. Very similar to my thoughts. For user migration, I would only consider leaving migrating Q from main site to its meta site.

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩ I don’t have easy access to any stats on that. I pretty much gave you a summary of what I could find. Some of this info is probably available on SEDE; at least, the user-directed migration stats. Mod flags won’t be, since they’re confidential. You’d need an employee with access & patience to get stats on mod migration flag success rates. Start pestering Shog9? In my subjective experience, I migrate a bit less than half of the custom migrate flags I handle, declining the rest. But my memory is fallible, mods are different, and there aren’t many custom migration flags raised

Comment: Got everything I need to know now, especially with the approximate precentage of helpful custom flags.