# How should non-English answers with code be handled in the Low Quality Answers queue?

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, english, low-quality-answers

I have seen [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/16217248) but it was not made clear specifically how answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34559327) should be handled. The answer includes a non-English description of a code block. Given the facts that:

1. Non-English content should be deleted.
2. Code-only answers should ***not*** be deleted.

How should I handle these contradictory rules in the case of non-English answers that contain code blocks? In practice they are code-only answers, because they contain no elaboration other than non-English text, but they are also non-English answers.

Should I:

- *Delete* or *Recommend Deletion* them? Or
- *Looks OK* them? Or
- *Edit* them to remove the foreign text?

I am not sure about the last one as that feels like vandalism.

[image]

Comment: From the linked post *"Answers not written in English should be flagged as "very low quality", although "not an answer" will also work."* If you're in the queue, then you could recommend deletion, as it's not an answer.

Comment: @ThomA But if they contain a code block, they're as useful as code-only answers, which ***shouldn't*** be deleted, so that's why I'm ambivalent.

Comment: "In practice they are code-only answers" - the non-English part could be spam, offensive, gibberish, a criticism that the following code is entirely unsuitable. That possibility surely is why which don't just pretend non-English parts of the post don't exist.

Comment: Could someone with enough reputation please post a screenshot of the answer since it's deleted?

Comment: @DonaldDuck some non english content (one line), above an arbitrary code block. I'm not sure why an image is needed for that. it's literally as described in the question

Comment: @KevinB I know. It's not required for me to understand the question, but I'm just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure why "Add a comment explaining the language requirements of Stack Overflow and Skip" is not one of the options...

Comment: @DonaldDuck I gotcha fam.

Comment: @francescalus The line above the code looks like Portuguese, and it also looks like it says something about "alter the column" and "It is recommended to use SizeBox ... of the Container."  That certainly looks like a valid description of what the code is doing.  In the hypothetical situation where the reviewer knows the language used in the non-English post, what would be SO's position on the reviewer translating the text themselves?  (Disclaimer:  I do not know Portuguese)

Comment: Oh never mind, I just saw the answer to that has already been posted here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392317/intervention-flags-for-migrating-ok-looking-foreign-language-questions-posted?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It looks like they don't want that because then the answer's poster won't understand any comments on the answer

Comment: @HereticMonkey Doesn't "Skip" mean someone else will have to deal with the same review later?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, but if the person handling the review doesn't feel equipped to handle the review, or normal advice is to Skip. Let others that are sure of the appropriate response and have the rep to vote to delete handle it. It was more a comment about the fact that there are other options and one can utilize them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The purpose of this question is to help us ***become*** people that are sure of the appropriate response instead.

Comment: Sure. That doesn't mean there aren't other options besides the ones listed. It certainly doesn't mean that skipping is not a good option to take, irrespective of the outcome of this question. *You don't have to take an action on every question presented*.

Comment: If anyone feels like adding an alt text to that screenshot, here's my proposition (I cannot add edit suggestion on meta): "A screenshot of the aforementioned answer. The post contains some kind of explanation in Portuguese followed by a code block."

Comment: I've now protected the specific question, since it seems to draw non-English answers by new users for some reason. There was a similar one posted & deleted previously.

Answer (score 11):

First note that code-only answers by themselves are already questionable and low-quality - they are almost never a good answer but indeed perhaps not bad enough to call for deletion. So the discussion here is about whether we should delete a  (almost definitely) low quality answer, or if we should deal with it in some other way.

Noting that it is not the end of the world if we happen to delete a low quality answer - our main concern should be about not deleting *high quality* answers. When moderating low-quality posts, don't overthink it. Preserving crap just for the sake of it isn't sensible.

The text before the code seems like a relevant explanation of what should be done to solve the problem, followed by the code. This text needed to be in English. It isn't really a code only answer.

The difference between an "almost code-only" answer in English and one another language, is that the one in another language cannot reasonably be understood by all readers. Whereas a pure code-only answer that only assumes that you know [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) (in this case) is acceptable, although probably of bad quality.

We cannot close answers waiting for the OP to fix them. Nor should we attempt to translate them unless maybe we are truly fluent in the language - which isn't expected. Also even when fluent, a translation always risks changing nuances or details, so it's always a radical edit probably best to avoid.

It is up to the person who posts the answer to know the site rules. If they do not want their content deleted, they have to post in English. The abnormal high frequency of posts in Portuguese, Spanish and Russian that SO experiences over time suggests that a lot of these posts are just users thinking they are using the respective non-English site and post on the English site by mistake.

In summary, the most sensible course of action is to delete these kind of posts.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with translation being inappropriate when translation can turn it into a valid answer. As with closing questions, radical edits that avoid the need to close/delete are justifiable on the general principle that we'd prefer to preserve value than to delete it. But definitely don't waste time translating something that would still need to be deleted or even downvoted once you finished translating it.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike As I wrote this, I changed the answer from a recommendation to translate in case you happen to be native speaking, into making no such recommendation. There are too many potential problems with proposing such:

Comment: First of all, people tend to overestimate their own language skill - someone who has just studied Portuguese but doesn't speak it fluently might decide to translate. Second, people who do speak the language fluently might decide to translate posts where they don't have sufficient domain knowledge. Third, it sends a message that posting in non-English is ok and that we will translate when it happens. Fourth (and most dangerous): Google translate or some other such form of Artificial Stupidity like ChatGPT.

Comment: I used machine translation for posts on another site.  I later learned that my text was being wrongly translated as "I would like to annoy you ..." And for this reason I wouldn't want to translate someone's answer unless I also had an understanding of the language.

Comment: "_so it's always a radical edit probably best to avoid._"  I don't know; google translate is pretty good now &, if there is code, you can probably improve the answer. From OP, eg: "_Below you will see that if you are going to change only the column width. Recommended to use SizeBox instead of Container._" If I'm familiar with the domain & can make the translation fit the code coherently with an edit for readability, like here, I'd recommend giving it a shot. Contra @Yogi, I think if I'm a native or fluent _English_ speaker and expert at the domain, I'm in a great position to improve the site

Answer (score 4):

As a user often finding zero upvoted answers and ugly written answers for very rare errors, I'm all for preserving value, even if the value *perceived, on first look* is of really low quality.  Although I can't speak for the answer in the OP's question, I consider some of these answers that I've found, diamonds in the rough.

Quality is hard to infer by just external examination - only based on external factors. If you don't understand both the languages(i.e., the code language and the written language), I suggest skipping, so that SMEs(who know the code language and therefore are able to better estimate the quality) may decide the best course of action for that specific case. If you however, want to take a action, I think editing to remove the foreign text and making it code only is the least value destroying option.