# How can I read comments on my edits on a deleted question when below 10k?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

I edited a (bad) question. Someone commented on my edit. The question got deleted.

I don't have the reputation to see deleted questions. How do I get to see the full comment? Right now I can only see in my inbox: "@jeffrey: please don't .... " (inbox popup actually ends in ellipsis).

I'd like to see the full comment and who commented. I'm not sure I agree, but I'm sure it's better for SO if I get to read and understand it. Is there any way do get that information short of building another 2.5K rep?

Link I don't have access to:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/119879583?noredirect=1

Comment: The comment is "*@Jeffrey Please don't translate posts for the OP. There's no guarantee that they understand the translation, even if it's correct. The OP may not understand posted answers either*"

Comment: You should probably just read [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/6045800)

Comment: @Tomerikoo that(your first comment) is helpful. "Translating a post of a non-English speaker sets up the OP, and anyone participating on the post, for a poor experience," I fail to see how having one's question deleted makes for a better experience, but that's OK, I'll follow this direction.

Comment: I agree that there is no special reason to delete the question. We should allow the OP sometime to translate themselves, and if they don't - it would Roomba anyway. Still, you should follow those guidelines and as I said, allow the OP to translate themselves

Comment: @Tomerikoo In general, I agree. However, there didn't seem to be much hope for that question to be improved enough to be reopened, even after translation. I saw no point in letting it keep on receiving downvotes, and so in this instance, I felt ok deleting the question.

Comment: @cigien I agree with you. After the above comment I checked the revisions and the OP actually edited non-English content back (and non-English comment) so this was probably a lost case. Just saying that in the general case I like to follow those posts I close for the rare chance that they are actually translated, to be able to reopen it (if worthy...)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can't.

That the item is shown in your inbox is an artefact from caching, and should disappear eventually.

Since comments are meant to address a post, once a post is deleted comments lose any relevancy. Once you are over 10k, those inbox notifications won't go away, and you'll be able to get to the posts while the comments exist.

Comment: Do comments on deleted posts appear in the inbox for 10k+ users?

Comment: @AdrianMole Sometimes! But mostly only due to bugs and race conditions. However, if the comment on the deleted post is left by a diamond-bearing moderator, then the user will always get a notification of it. (In fact, *any* comment left on a deleted answer will be notified. Pending notifications of comments are only cleared for users who haven't yet seen them when the post is deleted. It's just that the only users who can comment on deleted posts are moderators.)

Comment: Your claim that _once a post is deleted comments lose any relevancy_ is technically false, although I concede that it is the _intent_ of Stack Overflow that comments on a deleted post are irrelevant.  But in the actual real world, it may be a relevant message that failed to reach its intended recipient (in its entirety).  I think that the person that was @mentioned should still be able to read the entirety of the comment somehow.  I think that the hover-text for the notification should include the full text of the comment until the cache clears.