# The verified answer to the phpPgAdmin question was removed. Why?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [phpPgAdmin - Login Fail - Virtual Class--cannot instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299248/phppgadmin-login-fail-virtual-class-cannot-instantiate/68439945#68439945)

I won't insist too much, I just hoped that the solution that helped me would help other people, so I wonder what's wrong with the answer ?

Comment: This is the canonical on the topic [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: see also: [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/839601)

Comment: Cross-site: *[Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/)*

Answer (score 19):

[image]

> I wonder what's wrong with the answer?

The answer was "link only" (does not contain a solution, but a link to a potential solution), and was partly written in Russian.

Posts should be self-sufficient (links can support a post, but answers needs to be intelligible even if the link dies or breaks), and should be posted in English.

Comment: Relevant: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: I wrote in Russian after the block. Link to the solution.I checked - it works. It is the link, because there in more detail, much smarter people than me, explain the essence of the problem and the essence of the solution.

Comment: If we need to wait for smarter people to arrive to write a more detailed explanation, they can write the answer themselves. You mean you added text in Russian after the answer was deleted? Why would you do that? @Guest

Comment: it doesn't even link to "a solution". it links to a pull request with 171 changed files. How on earth is that a solution to a practical coding problem.

Comment: The solution that is marked as correct does not work correctly. But as I have already said , I will not insist, let your users suffer with the creation of databases after that.  Good luck

Comment: A smarter person has arrived. I can confirm that this is not an answer. ChrisF is pretty smart, too.

Comment: the link to that PR was already shared in a comment under the question. So anyone looking for it and desperate enough to merge that PR on their own branch can stop their suffering. No answer needed.

Comment: A Russian person has arrived. For anyone interested, the latter part of the answer was just a rant about downvotes.