# Are all the links to non-English language papers here providing benefit?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer, link-only-answers

I recently raised a flag on the [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558082/6296561), as being a link only answer, which was disputed. I can understand why this was disputed, as the answer does include additional detail (though I think it contained less when I flagged, and it may have been updated in the grace period, but I can't evidence that).

The bulk of the answer is links, however, and feel like they are more "self advertising". The fact that *none* of links are in English also, in my opinion, makes the links little more than noise. I am honestly not sure, however if I should edit them out. Is editing them out, when they can't be consumed by the majority of users on the site, the right call here? It feels like I would be changing the user's intent, which isn't the goal of edits.

To be honest, I probably wouldn't if it was 1 link, but posting 4 links, to different language articles, doesn't feel beneficial.

[image]

Comment: [Here's the link anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558082/6296561), because screenshots suck and strip all context (and I found it in a single search, so all you're doing is making it hard to see anything for people who rely on screenreaders, and making copy-pasting annoying)

Comment: Apart from that I *intentionally* don't want to promote the user's links, @Zoe ; and we are actually asked to therefore use images in such scenarios...

Comment: Note that if you change the text (f.ex. using the devtools) before taking a screen-dump, it's going to make it a lot harder to find.

Comment: For spam, yes, but typically accompanied with a link to the actual post, which actually doesn't change anything. it doesn't involve copying links over to meta and spreading them further (which is what an actual spammer would want. If that is spam and gets deleted as such, it won't be indexable anyway).

Comment: It looks like these are papers written by the person who wrote the answer. That means, if they own the copyright, they can choose to license it under CC-by-SA 4.0 as well as whatever they have it under now. If they do not wish to share it under the CC-by-SA 4 license (or whatever SO decides on next...), and the text they've written there does not answer the question, then it's not an answer.

Comment: Yes, the OP explicitly says that they have written them, @HereticMonkey : *"take a look over the papers **I wrote about that**"* As for if the if the text they have written there doesn't answer, I would, personally, say it does not as it isn't in English and [so] is an English Community (but that flag was disputed). Hence my asking if instead the links should be removed as noise.

Comment: *"makes the links little more than noise"* I disagree. IMO an article in another language can still be read using various translating tools. Google translate, for example, does a surprisingly good job at translating these and comes in build in Chrome - the browser that most people use. So it isn't completely useless.

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 we explicitly discourage people here to use translators to translate content on [so], I would personally say that extends to off site resources as well; as it poses the same problems.

Comment: @Larnu no, we discourage other people using translators on behalf of OP. We have no limitations on other uses of translators, though last I checked, resources that need them should be avoided as much as possible. Avoid != disallow, however. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/6296561, which doesn't apply here thanks to there being an answer that is in english, with non-english links being supplemental. Ref. rene's answer

Comment: Hm. They seem to have linked to their blog posts 4 times the last year ([SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1442658?Text=https%3A%2F%2Fsqlpro.developpez.com&UserId=12659872) to the rescue)

Comment: One should almost always post text as text, not as images, on SE/SO. If you want to not send them traffic, you could just remove the links from this question (you could omit them entirely or you could just not make them links, or you could strip the domain, although that doesn't seem too useful). If the idea is to have people review the actual links, then posting an image of them is rather detrimental to that. If that is not the idea, then there's presumably no reason to actually have the links here. "we are actually asked to therefore use images in such scenarios" - What? Who? When? Where?

Comment: *"One should almost always post text as text, not as images, on SE/SO. "* again not true @BernhardBarker . Please please, please... Don't copy a spammers post as text. It just promotes their spam more.

Comment: @Larnu "again not true" - according to whom? How would it promote their "spam" if you remove the links (or obfuscate whatever else they're trying to promote)?

Comment: If you remove the ability to see the links then it removes the point of this entire question @BernhardBarker ... My question is **about** said links... And according to whom? The mods... I have seen multiple times users be told to not requote spam because, and I know it seems silly to say, it's spam...

Comment: The advice of "don't post images of text/code" [is pretty common here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052). I don't think I've ever seen anyone try to make exceptions to that, so I'm basically just looking for a reference to support "we are ... asked" and the statements trying to assert the truth of such exceptions. Of course if there's no way to reference a spam post as text without further promoting it, then it's logical enough to post it as an image (if it avoids that), which may sound like an exception, but I don't think I've seen a case where that really applies, including this one.

Comment: I have seen it mentioned several times, @BernhardBarker ; if I find an undeleted comment from a mod advising a user to not repost spam as text I will link you to it. They do, however, tend to clean up such messages after the user has acknowledged them.

Comment: "My question is about said links" - but what do you actually want people to do with/about those links? I just really don't understand your thinking here. If you want people to actually go and click on those links to see what the page they link to is about, you're hindering that goal by not including the links. If you want them to simply read the URL of the link, then removing the domain should be sufficient to not promote it. If it's neither, then why do you need the links? If you want some committed people to check, but no-one else, then I guess I just disagree with that approach.

Comment: Well it is minimally beneficial, we have quite some French speaking people among us. But let's face it; the intent here was not to share relevant links. This was fully based on personal pride. Understandable... but not how you write an answer. This seems like a case where I would choose to do no more than refrain from voting altogether. Even though it does not provide a useful solution, it is a half-answer which provides details on what to research... it is slightly above bad.

Comment: Links have been burninated.

Comment: It seems to me that a small edit to add an `<hr>` and the text "Additional information (in French) written by me:" would have sufficed to distinguish the links from the answer.

Comment: “Take a look at the papers I wrote”, I would downvote an answer, even if the papers were not in French.  I want the information to my question, as an answer to my question, not buried in multiple papers. The answer has a lot to be desired.  There is a reason the author included the links, because the papers actually answered the question, unfortunately I don’t read French and this the answer isn’t helpful.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You don't have to reason about the links and/or where it lead to nor about the number of links when you flag as *Not an answer*.

You simply evaluate the post as if there are no links.

If you then end up with an answer that has lost all (give or take) its value / meaning you're dealing with a link-only answer. Applying that rule to your screenshot I see:

[image: Text part of answer with links]

And that reads as an answer to a question to me. The answer isn't link only, and an NAA flag is not the correct moderation option here.

If you feel the links are overt self-promotion, but can't find any other posts of the OP where they did the same thing, raise a custom moderator flag and ask to investigate the self-promotion. They might have deleted posts.

If they posted several answers already, adding numerous links to their off-site content and you have serious doubt the content behind these links is relevant to the question at hand / doesn't support the answer, raise a spam flag. Leave a comment so other flaggers can follow your line of thought.

If this is a one-off, but you feel French is not your cup of tea and you feel the answer by itself is too thin to be valuable, cast a downvote. Leave a comment if you have hopes the OP might be willing to write an excerpt for each of the articles they linked to.

Answer (score -8):

You forget one thing: English is not the only language on planet earth, and papers have been written before the existence of Stack Overflow...
I don't want to spend my time on simple translations, when I can use it help other people...

And finally, English is not my cup of tea... I wrote many books used in french university about SQL Language, and they are in FRENCH!

Comment: Non-English resources aren't that useful to many. The question will always be how helpful it is to link to them.

Comment: English is indeed not the only language, we have [sites in many other languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684). This site however is English only.