# An idea how to find and reward good edits

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Good edits are helpful, but there's a *lot* of trivial non-meaningful edits, so it's not that simple find and reward good ones properly. I'd like share an idea that may lead to a proper rewarding. Here it is, in a nutshell:

> (insert badge name): edit a post that got -2 by the last 2 votes and it gets +3 after the edit.

The "*by the last* 2 votes" bit makes sure it's not just a popular post that has some occasional downvotes but rather a post with distinct problems (make it "-3" to be really sure?); the "gets +3" bit (add "in a row"?) means that after the edit the post got considerably better. We also should make sure that this is the *only* edit between the events, otherwise a trivial edit may get rewarded too.

May be also the close status is worth considering: like "gets +3 or gets reopened and gets +1", because it's a much more frequent case.

Comment: So when someone posts a debugging question with a link to the code and it gets downvoted and closed we should incentivize users to, eg. edit the code from the external site into the question when it then receives upvotes and is reopened. Even if their work actually causes more problems because of licensing issues with the external code?

Comment: What should the reward be?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Apparently the (new) "Interpreter" badge.

Comment: The suggested edit queue is already brimming as it is.

Comment: I think the idea can work, considering we also have [Lifejacket](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/187/lifejacket) and [Lifeboat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/188/lifeboat) badges for answering badly received questions that got saved into the positive score.

Comment: I don't see why only bad posts can supposedly receive good edits. Also, this may make people take actions that are not really wanted, like translating [non-English content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/11682469) or maybe rewriting questions against the OP's intent etc.

Comment: @JeanneDark good objections, these scenarios look possible indeed and promote (although indirectly) unproper behavior, so I agree that the idea is not good enough

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by the objections that people could "abuse" this by rewriting turds into something completely different. This would imply that the edit changes the intent of the post, which is already a reason to reject such edits outright.

Comment: So we are going to reward people with a badge even when they make a thousand mediocre edits and happened to be lucky to be part of one edit that turns a question/answer around? No thank you. making one edit that happens to turn something around does not prove you're going to be consistent about it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi only for suggested edits. Full edits can slip under the radar quite easily.