# How do questions from other language users get translated?

Tags: discussion, languages

Fairly often, I come across questions that are clearly from another language. The code (variable/function names, comments, sometimes keywords, etc.) are all not in English. However, the question itself and the text outside code blocks are in English, (good English I might add).

Does Stack Overflow auto-translate these questions, or does the user do that themselves?

If the user is the one to translate the question, why do they not change the code?

Comment: A user doesn't "translate" their question. They just write it in English. Why should they translate their code, though?

Comment: "that are clearly from another language" I would guess that most people on [SO] are not native English speakers. On account that most people are not native English speakers.

Comment: Normal text can be google-translated into probably understandable but clunky English. If you try and google-translate code, you will probably get nonsense with more errors than it started with.

Comment: Keywords in other languages than English? [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript)?

Comment: I agree with @Cerbrus. The question does need to be in English per site regulations, but the code should not be changed to simply translate symbols and names. Some people have a hard enough time writing complete English to ask a question (not for lack of trying though, English as a language sucks), translating code to a language they don't know well is a refactor that might introduce other issues. We are not asked to be linguistics experts. Names in code can be translated by a reader if need be, as these are generally single words, and most programming language keywords are in English.

Answer (score 12):

Stack Overflow doesn't auto-translate posts. (Furthermore, [we don't allow anyone other than the OP to do translations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content).)

So if you see a post with no edit history, that's all from the OP.

> And if the user is the one to translate the question, why do they not change the code?

Probably because it would mean changing it all back when someone uses that code for the basis of their answer.

Answer (score 4):

> And if the user is the one to translate the question, why do they not
> change the code?

Because it is not a requirement. If we talk about symbol names, it is an easy way to introduce new typo errors, for one. I'd rather that people copy/paste their code as-is and not have a reason to touch it, only to redact some data if necessary.

You could say that it helps to translate comments, but comments shouldn't really be needed in code in a question/answer. That should be covered by the text.

Comment: "that people copy/paste their code as-is and not have a reason to touch it" I feel this conflicts somewhat with the goal of an [MRE]. We generally *don't* want the user's code, we want some code that reproduces the user's *problem*. Unless it's a very obscure Heisenbug, translating code is well part of creating an MRE.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi agree to disagree on that one. I have seen too many instances where the poster mucks it up where if they had literally copy-pasted what they had, it would have been just fine. In a perfect world what you say is true, but in our world people are sloppy as can be.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that someone writes the question in English doesn't mean that they normally use English for programming. There are Stack Overflow sites in English, Russian, Spanish, and Portuguese; if someone normally speaks and writes in another language wants to post a question, they'll need to post their question in one of those languages instead.

As @BSMP indicates, only the OP is allowed to translate their posts to the site's target language; auto-translate is not implemented on any Stack Overflow site, and it will not in principle be implemented, because we don't know whether the OP knows English/Russian/Spanish/Portuguese well enough to understand the answers or respond to comments.