# Is this locked answer on Stack Overflow Meta worded incorrectly regarding non-English speakers?

Tags: discussion, edits, meta, english

[Answer in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680)

> Non-English questions should not normally be translated into English by anyone other than the original poster (OP), unless there is indication in the OP's statements that they actually can speak English. Translating a question for a non-English speaker sets them and all participants up for a poor experience, due to the OP not being able to follow and respond to feedback from comments, understand answers, or get assistance from the Help Center

Correct me if I'm wrong:

Non-English speakers should ***not*** translate their own posts.

From this assumption I think the first phrase of the answer says the opposite: that non-English questions should not be translated by anyone other than the OP ***unless*** they speak English (in which case they can be translated by someone else (?)).

I think it can be worded a little more clearly.

Comment: I think you're trying too hard to find flaws in the description by disregarding context when parsing the text. It's quite clear - if OP doesn't speak English, then translating for them doesn't help OP. Simple.

Comment: "_Non English speakers should NOT translate their own posts_" that's not mentioned anywhere though? Why would we stop OP from translating their own posts if they are capable of doing that?

Comment: *"unless there is indication in the OP's statements that they actually can speak English"* I don't know why there would be an exception on this. I would think that posts should only be translated by the OP to make sure the context stays the same.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it says "Translating a question for a non-English speaker sets them and all participants up for a poor experience"

Comment: @aynber *a lot* of questions do not have context so nuanced that a translation might accidentally change them. "I have a problem with the loop. The variable `i` does not update" written in Zamundian will most likely be translated without any issues by any Zamundian speaker.

Comment: @Atovange immediately after it also says "_due to the OP not being able to follow and respond to feedback from comments, understand answers, or get assistance from the Help Center_" the assumption is that OP doesn't understand English, if they do understand English then this is obviously not an issue.

Comment: Probably better to just... not translate at all. If the op does it, great, else if it's a question worth asking for the community, someone can take it and ask it themselves in their own english words.

Comment: @VLAZ but the answer says the opposte: that only the OP should translate their own question unless they speak English (???)

Comment: @Atovange No, you're trying too hard again. You've joined the two clauses *disregarding what they are there for*. The post owner needs to be able to engage with the post. With clarifications, or comments, etc. That can be done 1. if OP speaks English and translates the post 2. If somebody else translates it but OP still needs to speak English. In both cases OP needs to be an English-speaker. We cannot *assume* that. The second case is the no assuming part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following separation made it clear to me (I had stumbled across that wording as well):

> Non-English questions should *not* **normally** *be translated* into English
> by anyone other than the original poster (OP)

- 'normally' refers to the exception, see the 'unless' part
- The reason to not translate the contribution is given in the latter part:

  > Translating a question for a non-English speaker sets them and all
  > participants up for a poor experience, due to the OP not being able to
  > follow and respond

Concerning the 'unless' exception

> **unless** there is indication in the OP's statements that they actually
> can speak English.

this does not mean that we should translate such a non-English contribution, just that we may translate it. OP is requested to write in English and do the translation, not the community.

---

My understanding from another angle:

- Default handling of non-English contributions is to flag / close them.
- Optional handling is to translate the contribution.

  - **Only if** there is a clear indication that any follow up communication can continue in English.

    - For example, when non-English fallback to the mother tongue was just by mistake (OP being laser focused on the technical part of the problem).
  - An example case for me would be when only the header or a single sentence isn't English but the main part is.

    - Then we could for sure leave a comment asking to translate that part as well, or do the translation in an edit potentially along with other improvements.
  - And also only when the editor is fluent enough in both languages to make sure the intended message stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is correct. Posters are encouraged to make their best effort to express their ideas in English. Neither fluency nor excellent grammar is required, only an ability to communicate. If a poster knows enough English to put together:

> i need helps code make "infinite loop" how wrong? python loop not end after 10 [code]

This is a sufficient translation into English for us to consider the poster an English speaker for purposes of participating here. We (the community) know that they know enough English to participate on this site. Assuming that the question meets all topicality requirements (e.g. providing an MCVE if required), we can then edit their post to something like:

> Why does this Python code loop infinitely? I expected it to loop to 10 and then terminate. [code]

Since we would already know that the poster speaks English, we can be reasonably confident that they will also be able to understand our edit and provide any appropriate feedback (e.g. if they feel that the edit changed their intended message). We also know that they are likely to be able to use an eventual answer written in English.

Comment: So why the "unless they speak English"? Why would other people be allowed to translate if the OP speaks English?

Comment: @Atovange I edited the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks I get it now. I still think it's pretty confusing and could be worded a bit more clearly :)

Comment: @Atovange It's only unclear when you focus on the conditionals. And ignore what they are conditionals *for*. "I like drinking tea but only when it's hot" doesn't mean I abhor tea because somewhere in the world there is bound to be a cup of cold tea thus making the conditional to my sentence "false".

Comment: @VLAZ I also think your example might be misiterpreted because it might mean that I like drinking tea when it's hot (outside, like in the summer). Not trying to be an ass but maybe it's a me problem as a non native English speaker.

Answer (score 2):

I think it reads clearly to me, but if I were to offer an improvement, I'd invert the expression.

> Unless there's an indication that the OP can actually speak English, non-English questions should not be translated into English by anyone other than their original poster (OP).

Comment: It still reads backwards to me:
if the OP doesn't speak English, why would they be the only one allowed to translate?

Comment: "that the OP can actually" should be "that the OP **can't** actually"

Comment: Because they _have_ to communicate in English. They're going to get comments _in English_ and answers _in English_. They have to make the effort themselves to communicate in English or they are not going to be able to participate in the site.

Comment: @HenryEcker you are completely correct, I'm not saying that that's wrong. I'm saying the answer in question says the opposite of that.

Comment: Is it more clear with some listed examples and not using the word speak? _e.g._ "Unless there's an indication that the OP can communicate English (like having asked  questions in English previously or responding to or posting comments in English), non-English questions should not be translated into English by anyone other than their original poster (OP).

Comment: Personally, I'm in favour of a more direct statement without a qualifier like: "Non-English questions should _only_ be translated into English by their original poster (OP)." IMO it's the responsibility of the asker to ask in the appropriate language (in the same way that it's the primary responsibility of the asker to ensure their question has enough details to be answered, is on topic, etc.)

Comment: It looks like the current wording is adapted from [Non-English posts can be translated to English, but this is usually done when there is some comment feedback from the OP that they can actually speak English.](/revisions/297680/14). I don't know why that exception was added or in what cases it's useful/been used. I don't know the context around that time (2019-07-10)