# Unable to understand question because of poor English

Tags: discussion, english

I often see questions from non-native speakers who are unable to communicate their problem. I see this issue addressed many places on meta, such as *[Handling questions from non native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291177/handling-questions-from-non-native-english-speakers)*, but these all suggest that the question is understood, but poorly written and can be edited to be more clear.

What should we do if we can not discern what is being communicated even after frequent attempts at clarifications from the asker because of poor English?

Comment: *"What should we do if we can not discern"* - Depends what you mean by "we". Sometimes I see a question where half a dozen people have left comments about the question being unclear, some close votes exist, and some people have left obviously misinformed answers, but I find I can work out what the OP means and provide a useful answer (which I *know* was useful because it got accepted with a comment about it having fixed the problem). I don't like to edit the question in those cases in case it turns out I am wrong, but I preface my answer with "I think you are asking [such and such]".

Comment: @n: _"I don't like to edit the question in those cases in case it turns out I am wrong..."_ -- but, of course, if and when your guess is confirmed by the answer being accepted, at that point it would the responsible thing to do to go back and edit the question so that it meets a higher quality bar.

Comment: Please, as a non native speaker, if you see a question that lacks proper wording to provide a understanding of the matter at hand, by all means, drop a comment saying so, so the user can take note and improve on it's answer. You will also do him a favor to point out his problems with english and maybe he can improve. All I know of english is from this kind of attitude. And I am very gratefull for it. Still needs to improve, thou...

Comment: @Malavos and the other comments. I always respond to poor English questions that I don't understand with requests for clarifications. This question is posted after about a dozen back and forth comments with an asker that left me no closer to understanding what he was trying to say, and I was honestly not sure what to do at that point. Of course, I will always continue to help those with poor English get their point across.

Comment: @Goose by all means, thank you for your understanding and helping those in need to overcome this language barrier. I salute your dedication and understanding.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan That question is about non english content. This question is about broken english content.

Comment: @Goose Retracted after further consideration.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Close it as "Unclear what you're asking".

This at *least* gives the OP a chance to continue to reply to questions for clarity and also prevents others from swooping in with incomplete or misinformed solutions.

Comment: I think it's also worth explaining your confusion in a comment in this case. Questions being closed/on hold is misunderstood by native english users, let alone non native speakers. Say what's confusing in particular so that they know what to focus on making clearer.

Comment: Do you really think it will enable them reformulate the problem in English? If someone isn't that good at English, no matter if we flag to close it, it won't let him improve his English skills overnight. I am more for semantics rather than syntax. Flagging to close can discourage a potentially good question

Comment: @TalhaIrfan if you spot clear, good, non-duplicate and on-topic interpretation of the question you can either post that question yourself (and link from original) or try to suggest particular way to edit question (which is likely less useful if poster has problems expressing their problem).

Comment: @TalhaIrfan:  My remarks are more geared towards the community who would be able to *eventually* help the OP better express their question with better English.  They're not going to learn overnight, believe me, but that doesn't mean that we can keep an incomplete or unintelligible question open to be answered, even incorrectly.  If the question has the *potential* to be good, we can often look past the poor grammar and improve it, although I do wonder how good a question with poor grammar actually is...

Comment: @TalhaIrfan, remember that we're talking about a question where we have _no idea_ what they're asking. We wouldn't know if it was a good question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov et al. I totally agree with your points!

Comment: In addition to the suggestion from @Super, I would point out that if a person is having trouble communicating in English, it can be helpful to encourage them to emphasize code and data, both of which should be able to be expressed unambiguously. Questions need a good MCVE anyway in most cases (it's a fallacy to think that only "help me debug this" questions do), and with a good MCVE, including clear descriptions of inputs and outputs (actual and desired), much of the English narrative can be omitted, or at the very least can be sub-par in quality.

Comment: Basically: if people would spend more time providing the technical details that are really required to present a good question, difficulty with the English language would not be such a problem, in many if not most cases.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this. Very much this. Add the code, and data and the whole thing becomes a non-issue. If the data is "sensitive" they can sterilize it and post that ... after they test it to ensure that the issue is still there. For other meta areas this might not be an option but for anything based on coding, the language and syntax that the OP is coding in, isn't negotiable. Simple code and data examples will display the issue and in the process of "sterilizing" data or code, if needed, they might solve their own problem. If not, we can definitely see their issue clearly.